# How to create, upload and install a package for PyPI?

Tags: python, packaging, distutils, python-sphinx, pypi

I wrote a little module and I would like to know what are the basic steps to package it in order to upload it to [PyPI](http://pypi.python.org/pypi):

- What is the file hierarchy?
- How should I name files?
- Should I use distutils to create PKG-INFO?
- Where should I include my documentation (made with sphinx)?

Comment: You might be interested in my [Python Projects article](https://martin-thoma.com/python-projects/)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I recommend reading [*The Hitchhiker's Guide to Packaging*](https://the-hitchhikers-guide-to-packaging.readthedocs.org/en/latest/). Specifically, you should look at the [*Quick Start* section](http://the-hitchhikers-guide-to-packaging.readthedocs.org/en/latest/quickstart.html), which describes how to:

> 1. Lay out your project
> 2. Describe your project
> 3. Create your first release
> 4. Register your package with the Python Package Index (PyPI)
> 5. Upload your release, then grab your towel and save the Universe!

You should also look at the [*Current State of Packaging*](http://the-hitchhikers-guide-to-packaging.readthedocs.org/en/latest/introduction.html#current-state-of-packaging) in the [*Introduction to Packaging* section](http://the-hitchhikers-guide-to-packaging.readthedocs.org/en/latest/introduction.html), as this helps untangle some of the confusion surrounding setuptools, distutils, distutils2, and distribute.

### Update Re: How to Name Files

The excerpt below is from [PEP8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), which answers your question about how to name files:

> Modules should have short, all-lowercase names.  Underscores can be used in the module name if it improves readability.  Python packages should also have short, all-lowercase names, although the use of underscores is discouraged.
>
> Since module names are mapped to file names, and some file systems are case insensitive and truncate long names, it is important that module names be chosen to be fairly short -- this won't be a problem on Unix, but it may be a problem when the code is transported to older Mac or Windows versions, or DOS.

Answer (score 3):

an example is always the best way to see how to do:

http://packages.python.org/an_example_pypi_project/

Answer (score 2):

Maybe [this CheeseShopTutorial](http://wiki.python.org/moin/CheeseShopTutorial) is of help for you. From there:

> Submitting Packages to the Package
>   Index
>
> If you have some Python modules or packages that you would like to
>   share with the Python community, we'd love to have them included in
>   the Python Package Index! First, if you haven't done so, you will want
>   to get your project organized. You might follow the guidelines at
>   ProjectFileAndDirectoryLayout. After that, you'll want to read the
>   Python documentation regarding creating distributions:
>   http://docs.python.org/distutils/index.html.

You can also check [Writing a Package in Python by Tarek Ziadé](http://zetcode.com/articles/packageinpython/) from Tarek's book "Expert Python Programming" where questions about development and distribution are addressed in great detail

Answer (score 1):

You should follow the tutorial [Packaging Python Projects](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/tutorials/packaging-projects/) and first, I explain how to create, upload and install a package for [TestPyPI](https://test.pypi.org/) and lastly, I explain it for [PyPI](https://pypi.org/):

First, create `packaging_tutorial` folder:

```
packaging_tutorial/
```

Then, create and activate [a virtual environment](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html) in `packaging_tutorial` folder:

For Linux and Mac:

```
python -m venv venv && . venv/bin/activate
```

For Windows:

```
python -m venv venv && . venv/Scripts/activate
```

Then, `venv` folder is created:

```
packaging_tutorial/
 └-venv/ # Here
```

Then, upgrade `pip`:

```
pip install --upgrade pip
```

Then, create `src/example_package_<YOUR_USERNAME_HERE>/__init__.py`(Empty file) and `example.py` and `tests` folder(Empty folder). *Replace `<YOUR_USERNAME_HERE>` with your username of TestPyPI, for example, `example_package_superkai` in my case:

```
packaging_tutorial/
 |-src/               # ↓ ↓ ↓ Here ↓ ↓ ↓ 
 |  └-example_package_<YOUR_USERNAME_HERE>/
 |     ├──__init__.py # Empty file
 |     └──example.py # Here
 |-tests/ # Empty folder
 └-venv/
```

Then, put the code below to `example.py`:

```py
def add_one(number):
    return number + 1
```

Then, create `pyproject.toml`, `LICENSE` and `README.md`:

```
packaging-tutorial/
 |-src/
 |  └-example_package_<YOUR_USERNAME_HERE>/
 |     |-__init__.py
 |     └-example.py
 |-pyproject.toml # Here
 |-README.md # Here
 |-LICENSE # Here
 |-tests/
 └-venv/
```

Then, put the code below to `pyproject.toml`. *Replace `<YOUR_USERNAME_HERE>` with your username of TestPyPI:

```ini
[build-system]
requires = ["hatchling"]
build-backend = "hatchling.build"

[project]               # ↓ ↓ ↓ Here ↓ ↓ ↓
name = "example_package_<YOUR_USERNAME_HERE>"
version = "0.0.1"
authors = [
  { name="Example Author", email="author@example.com" },
]
description = "A small example package"
readme = "README.md"
requires-python = ">=3.7"
classifiers = [
    "Programming Language :: Python :: 3",
    "License :: OSI Approved :: MIT License",
    "Operating System :: OS Independent",
]

[project.urls]
"Homepage" = "https://github.com/pypa/sampleproject"
"Bug Tracker" = "https://github.com/pypa/sampleproject/issues"
```

Then, put the text below to `README.md`:

```
# Example Package

This is a simple example package. You can use
[Github-flavored Markdown](https://guides.github.com/features/mastering-markdown/)
to write your content.
```

Then, put the text below to `LICENSE`:

```
Copyright (c) 2018 The Python Packaging Authority

Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining a copy
of this software and associated documentation files (the "Software"), to deal
in the Software without restriction, including without limitation the rights
to use, copy, modify, merge, publish, distribute, sublicense, and/or sell
copies of the Software, and to permit persons to whom the Software is
furnished to do so, subject to the following conditions:

The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be included in all
copies or substantial portions of the Software.

THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND, EXPRESS OR
IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY,
FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND NONINFRINGEMENT. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE
AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT HOLDERS BE LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER
LIABILITY, WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING FROM,
OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER DEALINGS IN THE
SOFTWARE.
```

Then, upgrade and run [build](https://github.com/pypa/build):

```
pip install --upgrade build && python -m build
```

Then, dict/...`whl` and `...tar.gz` are created. *`<YOUR_USERNAME_HERE>` is replaced with your username of TestPyPI:

```
packaging-tutorial/
 |-dist/              # ↓ ↓ ↓ Here ↓ ↓ ↓
 |  ├-example_package_<YOUR_USERNAME_HERE>-0.0.1-py3-none-any.whl
 |  └-example_package_<YOUR_USERNAME_HERE>-0.0.1.tar.gz
 |-src/               # ↑ ↑ ↑ Here ↑ ↑ ↑
 |  └-example_package_<YOUR_USERNAME_HERE>/
 |     |-__init__.py
 |     └-example.py
 |-pyproject.toml
 |-README.md
 |-LICENSE
 |-tests/
 └-venv/
```

Next, create an account and **API token** in TestPyPI. *Select **Entire account (all projects)** for **Scope**:

[image]

Then, an API token is created:

[image]

Next, install and upgrade [twine](https://github.com/pypa/twine):

```
pip install --upgrade twine
```

Then, upload `example_package_<YOUR_USERNAME_HERE>` package to TestPyPI. *Input `__token__` for **username** and the API token for **password**:

```
twine upload --repository testpypi dist/*
```

Then, `example_package_<YOUR_USERNAME_HERE>` package is uploaded to TestPyPI:

[image]

Next, install `example_package_<YOUR_USERNAME_HERE>` package from TestPyPI:

```py
pip install -i https://test.pypi.org/simple/ example-package-<YOUR_USERNAME_HERE>
```

Then, you can use `example.add_one()` from `example_package_superkai` package(module):

```
$ python
>>> from example_package_superkai import example           
>>> example.add_one(2)
3
```

Lastly, how to create, upload and install a package for PyPI is really similar to TestPyPI but there are some differences so for PyPI:

- Without `--repository testpypi`, upload `example_package_<YOUR_USERNAME_HERE>` package to PyPI:

  ```
  twine upload dist/*
  ```
- Without `-i https://test.pypi.org/simple/`, install `example_package_<YOUR_USERNAME_HERE>` package from PyPI:

  ```
  pip install example-package-<YOUR_USERNAME_HERE>
  ```

Comment: comprehensive answer utilizing `pyproject.toml` rather than `setup.py`.

Answer (score 0):

Matthew Rankin's answer tells you how to organize your project file heirarchy, but I find myself having to look up the commands to execute every time I want to update a project on PyPI.  So here they are:

[As described on the PyPi site](http://python-packaging-user-guide.readthedocs.org/en/latest/distributing/):

- Create a `setup.py` file ([here's an example](https://github.com/openworm/tracker-commons/tree/master/src/Python/setup.py))
- [Register a username/password with PyPi](https://pypi.python.org/pypi?%3Aaction=register_form)
- Do this:

  `python setup.py sdist
  python setup.py bdist_wheel
  python setup.py register
  twine upload dist/*`
- Look for your package on the PyPi site:
  https://pypi.python.org/pypi?%3Aaction=index
- On another machine try running:

  `pip install [your package name]`

Answer (score 0):

Most important thing is prepare your `setup.py` properly. Then:

- `setup.py sdist bdist_wheel` to generate distribution archives to  `dist/` folder
- `twine upload dist/*` to upload the archives to PyPi (with your PyPi username/password)

Here is an example of `setup.py`:

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

with open('README.md') as readme_file:
    README = readme_file.read()

with open('HISTORY.md') as history_file:
    HISTORY = history_file.read()

setup_args = dict(
    name='elastictools',
    version='0.1.2',
    description='Useful tools to work with Elastic stack in Python',
    long_description_content_type="text/markdown",
    long_description=README + '\n\n' + HISTORY,
    license='MIT',
    packages=find_packages(),
    author='Thuc Nguyen',
    author_email='gthuc.nguyen@gmail.com',
    keywords=['Elastic', 'ElasticSearch', 'Elastic Stack', 'Python 3', 'Elastic 6'],
    url='https://github.com/ncthuc/elastictools',
    download_url='https://pypi.org/project/elastictools/'
)

install_requires = [
    'elasticsearch>=6.0.0,<7.0.0',
    'jinja2'
]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    setup(**setup_args, install_requires=install_requires)
```

You can find more detail tutorial here: https://medium.com/@thucnc/how-to-publish-your-own-python-package-to-pypi-4318868210f9