# py2app- What's the difference between the "includes" and "packages" variables?

Tags: py2app

I'm trying to package a Linux program for Mac OS X using py2app.  My setup.py looks like this:

```
"includes": "sip,numpy,cherrypy,cPickle,md5,logging,shutil,xml.sax,PyQt4,PyQt4.QtCore",
"resources": "mnemosyne",
"iconfile": "pixmaps/mnemosyne.icns",
"packages": "mnemosyne,mnemosyne.pyqt_ui,mnemosyne.libmnemosyne,mnemosyne.libmnemosyne.translators,mnemosyne.libmnemosyne.card_types,mnemosyne.libmnemosyne.databases,mnemosyne.libmnemosyne.file_formats,mnemosyne.libmnemosyne.filters,mnemosyne.libmnemosyne.loggers,mnemosyne.libmnemosyne.plugins,mnemosyne.libmnemosyne.renderers,mnemosyne.libmnemosyne.render_chains,mnemosyne.libmnemosyne.schedulers,mnemosyne.libmnemosyne.controllers,mnemosyne.libmnemosyne.ui_components,mnemosyne.libmnemosyne.statistics_pages,mnemosyne.libmnemosyne.review_controllers,mnemosyne.libmnemosyne.criteria,mnemosyne.libmnemosyne.upgrades,mnemosyne.script,mnemosyne.webserver,openSM2sync,openSM2sync.binary_formats,openSM2sync.text_formats"
```

But I realized I can also include the modules like this:

```
"includes": "sip,numpy,cherrypy,cPickle,md5,logging,shutil,xml.sax,PyQt4,PyQt4.QtCore,mnemosyne.pyqt_ui.*,mnemosyne.libmnemosyne.*,mnemosyne.libmnemosyne.translators.*,mnemosyne.libmnemosyne.card_types.*,mnemosyne.libmnemosyne.databases.*,mnemosyne.libmnemosyne.file_formats.*,mnemosyne.libmnemosyne.filters.*,mnemosyne.libmnemosyne.loggers.*,mnemosyne.libmnemosyne.plugins.*,mnemosyne.libmnemosyne.renderers.*,mnemosyne.libmnemosyne.render_chains.*,mnemosyne.libmnemosyne.schedulers.*,mnemosyne.libmnemosyne.controllers.*,mnemosyne.libmnemosyne.ui_components.*,mnemosyne.libmnemosyne.statistics_pages.*,mnemosyne.libmnemosyne.review_controllers.*,mnemosyne.libmnemosyne.criteria.*,mnemosyne.libmnemosyne.upgrades.*,mnemosyne.script.*,mnemosyne.webserver.*,openSM2sync.*,openSM2sync.binary_formats.*,openSM2sync.text_format.*",
"resources": "mnemosyne",
"iconfile": "pixmaps/mnemosyne.icns",
```

I'm not a coder so I don't really understand what is going on here.  When should I use "includes" and when should I use "packages"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need to explicitly name everything that you've imported in the `include` field. py2app has a dependency walker which will be able to tell what you've used and bundle it in for you automatically. It doesn't always work for every module so the `include` and `exclude` are there to fine-tune the process. `exclude` is used if py2app bundles in some extra bits you don't use; you can unzip Contents/Resources/lib/pythonX.X/site-packages.zip to see what's included in the app.

Also I believe `include` is for including extra python modules that didn't get automatically included where as `packages` will include everything in that location, not just python bits- so any and all files and file types in those locations. (I can't find a link or anything to confirm this, but from my experience this is what I understand).

Comment: Adding our package to `packages` didn't include text files, apparently it doesn't includes every file type.

Comment: @MichielKauw-A-Tjoe I think you want `datafiles` for including other file types, images/text files etc.

Comment: The `data_files` (with underscore) argument does add files, but doesn't add non-Python files inside a package, or copy the entire path at which the files are located, which is what I need. Instead, the folder at which it points is copied into `Resources` next to `lib`, where the packages are stored. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1):

They should be used for modules and packages respectively, it says so in the `py2app` options reference:

https://pythonhosted.org/py2app/options.html

Where packages are "dotted module names" according to http://www.network-theory.co.uk/docs/pytut/Packages.html (reference found in this topic: [What's the difference between a Python module and a Python package?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7948494/whats-the-difference-between-a-python-module-and-a-python-package)).

Comment: Edit queue is full: but for clarity: _"*Includes* should be used for modules, *packages* should be used for packages."_