# what does importing a module in python mean?

Tags: python

I am new to python and found that I can import a module without importing any of the classes inside it. I have the following structure --

```
myLib/
    __init__.py
    A.py
    B.py

driver.py
```

Inside driver.py I do the following --

```
import myLib
tmp = myLib.A()
```

I get the following error trying to run it. 
    AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute A

Eclipse does not complain when I do this, in fact the autocomplete shows A when I type myLib.A.

What does not it mean when I import a module and not any of the classes inside it?

Thanks

P

Comment: `myLib` is not a `module` but a `package`. `A` and `B` are modules.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Python is not Java. `A` and `B` are not classes. They are modules. You need to import them separately. (And `myLib` is not a module but a package.)

The modules `A` and `B` might themselves contain classes, which might or might not be called `A` and `B`. You can have as many classes in a module as you like - or even none at all, as it is quite possible to write a large Python program with no classes.

To answer your question though, importing `myLib` simply places the name `myLib` inside your current namespace. Anything in `__init__.py` will be executed: if that file itself defines or imports any names, they will be available as attributes of `myLib`.

If you do `from myLib import A`, you have now imported the *module* `A` into the current namespace. But again, any of its classes still have to be referenced via the `A` name: so if you do have a class `A` there, you would instantiate it via `A.A()`.

A third option is to do `from myLib.A import A`, which does import the *class* `A` into your current namespace. In this case, you can just call `A()` to instantiate the class.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do

```
from mylib import A
```

Because `A` is not an attribute of `__init__.py` inside `mylib`

When you do `import mylib` it imports `__init__.py`

See my answer.
[About packages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7948494/whats-the-difference-between-a-python-module-and-a-python-package/7948504#7948504)