# Python modules' paths

Tags: python, module, package

In some Python scripts I see the following imports:

```
import fileA
import someDir.fileB
from fileC import functionA
```

There exist corresponding files `fileA.py`, `someDir/fileB.py` and `fileC.py`. However, while looking in the [Requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/) source code, I found this in the `__init__.py` file:

```
from requests.packages.urllib3.contrib import pyopenssl
```

In this case, `requests` is the CWD and `packages.urllib3.contrib.pyopenssl.py` is the file. Why does this defy convention? I do see that the `packages.urllib3.contrib` directory does also have a `__init__.py` file, which [seems to be related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7948494/whats-the-difference-between-a-python-module-and-a-python-package).

Furthermore, I'm not sure if it is related but I think it is so I post it here. In my script I have the folder `kennethreitz/requests`, since the application depends on the Requests module but I'm deploying it to environments which might not have Requests installed. However, simply adding to the file `import kennethreitz.requests` is not including the Requests module. I `import kennethreitz.requests.__init__` and a few other obvious permutations but I cannot get the module to import. **How can I package Requests with my code?** The obvious [Google searches](https://www.google.com/search?q=package+library+with+python) are not helping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`requests` is using an *absolute* import. You cannot arbitrarily nest packages into other directories and still expect things to work.

Instead, add the `kennethreitz` directory (which should **not** have a `__init__.py` file) to your `sys.path` module search path. That way the `requests` module will still be importable as a top-level package.

Next, you may want to look into Python packaging, dependencies and using a tool like `pip` or `zc.buildout` to deploy your code for you. Those tools handle dependencies for you and will install `requests` as required. See the [Python Packaging User Guide](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/) for an introduction.