# dir(package) not listing out containing modules in python

Tags: python, dir

I have a directory structure as follows:

TestCases:

- `__init__.py`
- `agent_cases.py` # contains many classes eg: foo, bar.

TestSuite:

- `__init__.py`
- `main.py`

In `main.py,`

```
import TestCases
dir(TestCases.agent_cases)
```

I expect to find the list of classes including foo, bar, etc. I get an error as follows:

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'agent_cases'
```

Also `dir(TestCases)` doesn't return the module names under it.
What am I missing? Please help.

Comment: See [this reponse](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7948672/1881610) in a related question.

Answer (score 2):

you either need to import `agent_cases` in `__init__.py` or to directly import `TestCases.agent_cases` in your code.

This is because modules in a directory module is not imported automatically, you need to do it explicitely, or document it so your users import them directly.

Comment: I have imported TestCases.agent_cases in main.py. Is that not sufficient?

Comment: yes, but `agent_cases` will still not appear as member of `TestCases`, it's just an import path.

Answer (score 0):

Sub-modules are not automatically imported when you import the package. You can explicitly import `agent_cases` in the `TestCases.__init__` module:

```
import agent_cases
```

if you expect the module to always be imported with the package.

Comment: Thanks. I needed to "import TestCases.agent_cases". This worked. I didn't include in the init file as I wouldn't require it everytime. Thanks for the direction anyway.