# dir function not showing all package contents

Tags: python

I'm trying to get a list of all modules inside a python package. This is my directory structure:

```
foo/
   __init__.py
   bar.py
   dumb.py
   dog.py
```

I'm trying to list all modules like this:

```py
import foo

dir(foo)  
# ['__builtins__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__']
```

As you can see the dir function doesn't list the modules of the package. But if I do something like this look what happens:

```py
import foo
import foo.bar

dir(foo)  
# ['__builtins__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__', 'bar']
```

Can someone explain what just happened? There's a way I can list all modules names without importing them?

Comment: Maybe you're confusing Python's `dir` with Window's `dir`. The former really only lists you the attributes or members of an object. This kind of works to list files (modules) that are in a folder (package), but only if the modules are in fact loaded and therefore accessible as attributes of the package.

Comment: Following on @Jeronimo: you could use `os.walk` to scan the directory of `foo` to find the files in there, if you *really* wanted to avoid importing everything.

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/23829845/407651

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should first import all the foo' submodules if you want python to recognise it. Just change your line `import foo.bar` for `from foo import *`. I think it should work :D. You can also import them in the `__init__.py` file. Then you can filter the output of `dir(foo)` with:

```
list(map(lambda x: not x.startswith("_"), dir(foo)))
```

Comment: Have you tried to import it in the `__init__.py` file?

Comment: I mean, just write in the `__init__.py` file the import statement and try running your code

Answer (score 2):

Python's import mechanism isn't a directory listing, when you import `foo` only `foo` is imported along with a file named `__init__.py` (if it exists in that directory).

When a module is *imported* its code is executed and stored within `sys.modules`, and a use of `__init__.py` is that you use it to `from . import bar` thus allowing `import foo` to import whatever it is from the directory that you want.

When you ran your second line `import foo.bar` thus you told the interpreter to import `bar` (be it a file named `bar.py` or a directory named `bar` (with or without an `__init__.py`)) and that this `bar` module is a child of the `foo` module (the `.` which connects them).

p.s. this is a small abstraction on the import system, but I hope this answers your question.

**EDIT:** To get your desired results, you can use the imported modules metadata to inspect the folder imported.

waving my hands over the internals, here is a snippet

```
[pyimport]
$: tree
.
├── mod1
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── inner.py
└── mod2
    └── inner.py

[pyimport]
$: py --no-banner

In [1]: import mod1

In [2]: import mod2

In [3]: mod1.__file__
Out[3]: '/home/yhoffman/Sandbox/pyfiles/pyimport/mod1/__init__.py'

In [4]: mod1.__path__
Out[4]: ['/home/yhoffman/Sandbox/pyfiles/pyimport/mod1']

In [5]: mod2.__file__

In [6]: mod2.__path__
Out[6]: _NamespacePath(['/home/yhoffman/Sandbox/pyfiles/pyimport/mod2'])

In [7]: import os

In [8]: os.listdir(os.path.dirname(mod1.__file__))
Out[8]: ['__init__.py', 'inner.py', '__pycache__']

In [9]: os.listdir(mod1.__path__[0])
Out[9]: ['__init__.py', 'inner.py', '__pycache__']

In [11]: os.listdir(mod2.__path__._path[0])
Out[11]: ['inner.py']
```

Comment: I understood, thanks. So, do you know any way to do what I'm trying to do? :P

Comment: For a deep dive in python's `import` mechanism, I would reccomend you checking out David Beazley's great course named **Modules live and let die** https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0oTh1CXRaQ0

Answer (score 1):

You could also use the pkgutil module

```
import pkgutil

[name for _, name, _ in pkgutil.iter_modules(['foo'])]
```

**Note**: the parameter of iter_modules is a list of paths to modules.

Comment: Doesn't worked. For me this code returns an empty list