# ImportError only when I use docker

Tags: python, docker

I can run a script fine without docker, but when I have to use docker I run it and I get an import error: no module named c.H.

In my docker container, I can do:

python

```
 import c.H
```

Everything works fine. But the second I try to run script.py, I get the import error that there is no module named c.H

I do not get this error when I don't use docker.

Comment: Have you installed the module in your container?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it's possible that the python version you are using inside the container is different from the python version the script is using. And different version of python may have different packages installed. You could check the python version the script is using from the shebang line.
The shebang line should look something like the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to import a module from a package. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7948504/7584643) answer to learn the difference between a module and a package. Your problem may be that your package isn't recognized as a package due to a missing __ init.py__ file. Add an empty one to the c directory if you don't already have one.

Comment: this is not very docker specific