# ValueError: Attempted relative import in non-package

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have two Python files, one stored in the location `/Python/plata.py`, and another in the location `/Python/tao/mock.py`. This is what my `plata.py` file looks like::

```
def printSomething():
    print 'This is a test.'
```

I'm trying to import the `printSomething()` function inside my `mock.py` file as follows:

```
from . import plata

plata.printSomething()
```

However, this is the error I'm encountering:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/manas/Python/tao/mock.py", line 1, in <module>
from . import plata
ValueError: Attempted relative import in non-package
```

I've included the `__init__.py` files in locations `/Python/__init__.py` and `/Python/tao/__init__.py` as well. However, I'm still encountering the same error.

What seems to be wrong here?

Comment: Are you running `mock.py` directly (as opposed to importing it from somewhere else)?

Comment: @BrenBarn I'm running it directly.

Answer (score 5):

The parent directory of the package is *not* being included in `sys.path` for obvious security reasons. But, anyway...

```
import sys
sys.path.append('..')

import plata
```

Hope this helps you!

Answer (score 2):

See [What's the difference between a Python module and a Python package?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7948494/whats-the-difference-between-a-python-module-and-a-python-package) for an explanation of Module vs Package. The short of it is that your `Python` directory is not a package. `plata.py` is a stand alone module and should be imported as `import plata`.

Comment: The linked reason for this being a duplicate still does not explain to OP why adding random `__init__.py` files is not the answer. `tao` is a package, `plata` is a module. My linked answer is the real reason why this does not work.