# Why does running a submodule (python -m a.c) also import the containing module?

Tags: python

Given:

## `tree`

```
~/dir                                                                          
▶ tree
.
├── a
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── c.py
└── b.py

1 directory, 3 files
```

## `*.py` files

```
~/dir                                                                          
▶ tail -n +1 **/*.py                                                  
==> a/__init__.py <==
print(__name__)
import a.c

==> a/c.py <==
print(__name__)

==> b.py <==
print(__name__)
import a
```

## I/O

```
~/dir                                                                          
▶ python3 -m a.c
a
a.c
__main__
```

Module `a.c` has no dependencies on module `a`. So, why does Python run module `a` as if it were importing it? To me this is surprising behavior. I didn't expect running a script without imports would cause the script itself to be imported and evaluated twice. Wouldn't this be dangerous for the scripts that don't use the protection of `if __name__ == "__main__"`?

What is the justification for this behavior? Why does Python need to evaluate the containing module upon running its submodule?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Module a.c has no dependencies on module a. So, why does Python run module a as if it were importing it

[From the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#regular-packages):

> > Importing parent.one will implicitly execute `parent/__init__.py` and `parent/one/__init__.py`. Subsequent imports of `parent.two` or `parent.three` will execute `parent/two/__init__.py` and `parent/three/__init__.py` respectively.

---

> To me this is surprising behavior. I didn't expect running a script without imports would cause the script itself to be imported and evaluated twice.

No, this isn't suprising. Think about this: whatever objects are exposed by package `a` in your example is controlled by `a/__init__.py`. The interpreter now has to evaluate `a/__init__.py` to find out if `a.c` exists at all. And in the process, the print statement is executed. Further, no module is imported twice. It is imported only once -- although you could technically write import statements multiple times.

Comment: I didn't think about objects exposed by `__init__.py`.

Answer (score 1):

> Module a.c has no dependencies on module a

You are confusing a package with a module.

```
`a` is a package
`c` is a module within package `a`
```

There is a dependency: `a.c` is a member of package `a`.

Questions about this are common

[What's the difference between a Python module and a Python package?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7948494/whats-the-difference-between-a-python-module-and-a-python-package)

[Module vs. Package?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/111871/module-vs-package)

> So, why does Python run module a as if it were importing it? To me this is surprising behavior

When you import module `a.c`, python processes package `a` which includes executing code in the `a/__init__.py` and then module `c.py`

Q: Why?

A: Because that is what the language states it will do. :) (I know, that isn't really the *why* you meant.)

Q: Why? As in, "why would it do that, what good can that be?"

A: The package level init might do something useful.

The package init can provide things, and the members can count on the package being execute before the member module starts.

You put `c` into package `a` for a reason.

People can use packages simply for structural organization.  If you have Java experience you may see the dots as just how you organize classes.  If you are only using the `a` for this reason, leave the `__init__.py` empty and all will be as you expect.

But the package `a/__init__.py` allows other abilities.  It does require a care to use correctly, but is available when you need it.

> Wouldn't this be dangerous for the scripts that don't use the protection of `if __name__ == "__main__":`?

Yes, you need to clearly know what are scripts meant to be run (for example `python b.py`) and what are modules meant as containers for classes and functions.

In general, modules are not mean to be executed as stand alone scripts.   The common exception is during test and development.  Then you will regularly see bits of test code

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    x = somefunction()
    print(x)
    a = SomeClass()
    y = a.foo()
    print(y)
```