# How to import from Qt:: namespase (Qt5, Python3.x)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, qt, pyqt5, qt5

For my application, I need to set some widget parameters like alignment (`Qt::AlignBottom`) and others. But I can't import them (other PyQt5 stuff imports without any issues).

Using this code

```
from PyQt5 import Qt

progressBar = QProgressBar(splash)
progressBar.setAlignment(Qt.AlignBottom)
```

I got the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "run_app.py", line 50, in <module>
    runSemApp(sys.argv)
  File "run_app.py", line 32, in runSemApp
    progressBar.setAlignment(Qt.AlignBottom)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'AlignBottom'
```

And using this one works:

```
from PyQt5.Qt import *

progressBar = QProgressBar(splash)
progressBar.setAlignment(Qt.AlignBottom)
```

Though I have a working solution, I would like to import only `Qt.AlignBottom` and not `*`. Also, why doesn't `Qt.AlignBottom` work with `from PyQt5 import Qt`?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think the confusion here is that PyQt has a special virtual module called `Qt`, which imports *everything* into a single namespace. This is a quite useful feature, but it's a real shame that the name clash with `QtCore.Qt` wasn't avoided.

In the first example, the error can be "fixed" by using the somewhat weird-looking `Qt.Qt.AlignBottom`. But obviously, explicitly importing from `QtCore` is a much better solution. It's also worth noting that the `PyQt5` package is a lazy loader, so `import PyQt5` will just import an empty namespace with no access to the other modules.

Answer (score 7):

You can do this

```
>>> from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
>>> Qt.AlignBottom
64
>>>
```

You can't import `AlignBottom` only because QtCore is not a package itself, it's just a module on it's own (a single file). it's important to know that **all packages are modules, but not all modules are packages**

so this won't work

```
import PyQt5.QtCore.Qt

ImportError: No module named 'PyQt5.QtCore.Qt'; 'PyQt5.QtCore' is not a package
>>> import PyQt5.QtCore
>>> QtCore
<module 'PyQt5.QtCore' from '/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/PyQt5/QtCore.so'>
>>> import PyQt5
>>> PyQt5
<module 'PyQt5' from '/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/PyQt5/__init__.py'>
>>>
```

Looking at the output you can see that `QtCore` is a single file which contains a class `Qt` that contains other classes and methods on which `AlignBottom` is part of, you can see that with.

```
>>> from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
>>> help(Qt)
```

On the otherhand PyQt5 is a package (folder containing other modules) points to it's `__init__.py`

i'll suggest you read the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html) on Modules and this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7948494/whats-the-difference-between-a-python-module-and-a-python-package) question

Comment: I think the confusion here is that PyQt has a special virtual module called `Qt`, which imports *everything* into a single namespace. This is a quite useful feature, but it's a real shame that the name clash with `QtCore.Qt` wasn't avoided. In the OPs first example, the error can be "fixed" by using the somewhat weird-looking `Qt.Qt.AlignBottom`. But obviously, explicitly importing from `QtCore` is a much better solution. It's also worth noting that the PyQt5 package is a *lazy loader*, so `import PyQt5` will just import an empty namespace with no access to the other modules.

Comment: @ekhumoro, if you post your comment as the answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 0):

If you''re using PySide - as of **Pyside6**, the QtCore has been refactored. The alignment flags are in the AlignmentFlag module. The following works for me (Python 3.10, Pyside 6, Ubuntu 22.04).

```
import Pyside6.QtCore as qtc
            
my_align = qtc.Qt.AlignmentFlag.AlignCenter | qtc.Qt.AlignmentFlag.AlignVCenter

title_label.setAlignment(my_align)
```