# AttributeError: 'PySide2.QtCore.Qt.Alignment' object has no attribute 'testFlag'

Tags: python, pyside, pyside2

I am using Pyside2. I get the error

```
AttributeError: 'PySide2.QtCore.Qt.Alignment' object has no attribute 'testFlag'
```

for this piece of code

```
if (self.m_alignment.testFlag(Qt.AlignTop)):
```

The alignment is defined thus:

```
m_alignment = Qt.AlignTop | Qt.AlignRight
```

Is there something I am doing wrong? Or is there another way to check for an alignment flag in PySide2? Been stuck at this for some time.

Comment: It seems that PySide2 does not support QFlags, report it.

Comment: Use bitwise AND: `if self.m_alignment & Qt.AlignTop`. There is no way to directly support `QFlags` in pyside/pyqt because it is a template class (which is specific to c++).

Comment: It seems Qt is a special virtual module of either PyQt5 and/or PySide2.QtCore. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39317267/6501141) and that whole Q&A for more details. Not 100% sure that will directly fix this though.