# Python import xml does not include xml.etree.ElementTree

Tags: python, xml, module, namespaces

I like to use full namespaces in python when it comes to modules/libraries for readability. I'm wondering why this doesn't work the the xml library. I figure `import xml` will also import etree and everything else in the namespace. At least that's behavior I've noticed for other modules.

```
$ ptpython
>>> import xml

>>> dir(xml.etree.ElementTree)
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'etree'
'module' object has no attribute 'etree'

>>> import xml.etree.ElementTree

>>> dir(xml.etree.ElementTree)
['Comment', 'Element', 'ElementPath', 'ElementTree', 'HTML_EMPTY', 'PI',...]
```

Two questions:

1. Why is this happening with the xml library?
2. Is there a way to import it all with something short like `import xml`?

Comment: This answer is quite relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7948672/771848.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I figure import xml will also import etree and everything else in the namespace. At least that's behavior I've noticed for other modules.

Importing a package doesn't automatically import submodules in that package.  It's true that *some* packages do this for you as a convenience, but it's not default behavior.  In this case, you need to do what you already figured out: `import xml.etree.ElementTree`.

Answer (score 2):

this is a compatibility issue with previous versions of defusedxml with python3.6 ... if you are still running into the error now, upgrade defusedxml to version  0.6.0. Worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `from xml.etree import ElementTree` this works for me.