# sklearn doesn't have attribute 'datasets'

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I have started using sckikit-learn for my work. So I was going through the [tutorial](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/tutorial/basic/tutorial.html) which gives standard procedure to load some datasets:

```
$ python
>>> from sklearn import datasets
>>> iris = datasets.load_iris()
>>> digits = datasets.load_digits()
```

However, for my convenience, I tried loading the data in the following way:

```
In [1]: import sklearn

In [2]: iris = sklearn.datasets.load_iris()
```

However, this throws following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-db77d2036db5> in <module>()
----> 1 iris = sklearn.datasets.load_iris()

AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'datasets'
```

However, if I use the apparently similar method:

```
In [3]: from sklearn import datasets

In [4]: iris = datasets.load_iris()
```

It works without problem. In fact the following also works:

```
In [5]: iris = sklearn.datasets.load_iris()
```

I am completely confused about this. Am I missing something very trivial? What is the difference between the two approaches?

Comment: try `sudo pip install --upgrade sklearn`

Comment: @DaveQ: That doesn't help. Anyway I have 0.18.1

Answer (score 63, accepted):

`sklearn` is a [package](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-regular-package). [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7948672/3642398) said it very succinctly:

> when you import a package, only variables/functions/classes in the `__init__.py` file of that package are directly visible, not sub-packages or modules.

`datasets` is a sub-package of `sklearn`. This is why this happens:

```
In [1]: import sklearn

In [2]: sklearn.datasets
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-325a2bfc35d0> in <module>()
----> 1 sklearn.datasets

AttributeError: module 'sklearn' has no attribute 'datasets'
```

However, the reason why this works:

```
In [3]: from sklearn import datasets

In [4]: sklearn.datasets
Out[4]: <module 'sklearn.datasets' from '/home/ethan/.virtualenvs/test3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/datasets/__init__.py'>
```

is that when you load the sub-package `datasets` by doing `from sklearn import datasets` it is automatically added to the namespace of the package `sklearn`. This is one of the lesser-known ["traps" of the Python import system](http://python-notes.curiousefficiency.org/en/latest/python_concepts/import_traps.html#the-submodules-are-added-to-the-package-namespace-trap).

Also, note that if you look at the [`__init__.py` for `sklearn`](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/__init__.py#L60) you *will* see `'datasets'` as a member of [`__all__`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#importing-from-a-package), but this only allows you to do:

```
In [1]: from sklearn import *
In [2]: datasets
Out[2]: <module 'sklearn.datasets' from '/home/ethan/.virtualenvs/test3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/datasets/__init__.py'>
```

One last point to note is that if you inspect either `sklearn` or `datasets` you will see that, although they are packages, their type is `module`. This is because all packages are considered modules - however, not all modules are packages.