# How to import r-packages in Python

Tags: python, r

I'm a bit troubled with a simple thing. I was trying to install a package called hunspell, but I discovered it is originally an R package. I installed this version: https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/r-hunspell, but I'm not being able to import it. Is this package supposed to work with Python? Should I use `rpy2` to import it? First time using cross-platform packages so I'm a bit confused.

Just to be clear, `import hunspell` brings `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'hunspell'` and `import r-hunspell` brings `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`.

I also noticed that this package, also installed an `r-base` package, but I'm also not sure how to import that.

Comment: R packages are for R not Python -two different languages. Conversely, you cannot run Python modules in R. However, these two have interfaces, `rpy2` in Python and `reticulate` in R (not unlike Java extensions: `Jython` and `rJava`) that can talk to each other, indirectly using their installed libraries.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

After running in the command line:

```
pip install rpy2
```

or with the "!" if you're in a Jupyter Notebook. **The following procedure will answer your issue**, based on the official [documentation](https://rpy2.readthedocs.io/en/version_2.8.x/introduction.html):

```
# Using R inside python
import rpy2
import rpy2.robjects.packages as rpackages
from rpy2.robjects.vectors import StrVector
from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr
utils = rpackages.importr('utils')
utils.chooseCRANmirror(ind=1)

# Install packages
packnames = ('hunspell', 'some other desired packages')
utils.install_packages(StrVector(packnames))

# Load packages
hunspell = importr('hunspell')
```

If you want to access specific functions in this module you could check out [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59462337/importing-any-function-from-an-r-package-into-python) answer or [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49776568/calling-functions-from-within-r-packages-in-python-using-importr) answer too.