# Problems with bnlearn as library regarding float numbers

Tags: python

I'm trying this notebook but on float numbers

https://github.com/erdogant/bnlearn/blob/master/notebooks/bnlearn.ipynb

Has anyone used "structure_learning.fit()" from bnlearn with float numbers?

My chart is blank. When I run a simple correlation on my dataframe, I get results so is not a a dataframe problem.

Another hint about my hypotheses : When I transform my float to binary, it works

Comment: If you want to use continuous variables you could try http://openturns.github.io/otagrum/master/  or you could try calling [the actual R package `bnlearn`](https://www.bnlearn.com/) using a py/R wrapper ; example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59462337/importing-any-function-from-an-r-package-into-python?answertab=votes#tab-top). I seem to remember seeing someone working on a fuller python wrap of the R package on github but can't find it now (due to unfortunate naming of this new, unrelated, bnlearn python package)

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot. I'm going to try this and get back at you. Thanks for the help, is better than nothing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bnlearn in python only works with binary and not with cont values. This library is an adaptation of an R library so not everything is done. Currently P(A/B) can be done only for binary problems in this library. Please check the math of P(A/B) to understand

Comment: Its not a "adaptation of an R library ". It wraps functionality of https://github.com/pgmpy/pgmpy, so unrelated code-wise to R's bnlearn