pandas.read_sas() fails when bad timestamps exist
I have a file with some bad timestamps and the read_sas method in pandas fails. There seems to be no recourse. The file is read fine in R with haven package, and the bad timestamps are identifiable.
df = pd.read_sas('my_sas_file.sas7bdat')

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/io/sas/sas7bdat.py", line 83, in _convert_datetimes
    return pd.to_datetime(sas_datetimes, unit=unit, origin="1960-01-01")
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/tools/datetimes.py", line 1068, in to_datetime
    values = convert_listlike(arg._values, format)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/tools/datetimes.py", line 393, in _convert_listlike_datetimes
    return _to_datetime_with_unit(arg, unit, name, tz, errors)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/tools/datetimes.py", line 557, in _to_datetime_with_unit
    arr, tz_parsed = tslib.array_with_unit_to_datetime(arg, unit, errors=errors)
  File "pandas/_libs/tslib.pyx", line 312, in pandas._libs.tslib.array_with_unit_to_datetime
pandas._libs.tslibs.np_datetime.OutOfBoundsDatetime: cannot convert input with unit 's'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/util/_decorators.py", line 331, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/io/sas/sasreader.py", line 175, in read_sas
    return reader.read()
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/io/sas/sas7bdat.py", line 742, in read
    rslt = self._chunk_to_dataframe()
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/io/sas/sas7bdat.py", line 792, in _chunk_to_dataframe
    rslt[name] = _convert_datetimes(rslt[name], "s")
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/io/sas/sas7bdat.py", line 85, in _convert_datetimes
    s_series = sas_datetimes.apply(_parse_datetime, unit=unit)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py", line 4771, in apply
    return SeriesApply(self, func, convert_dtype, args, kwargs).apply()
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/apply.py", line 1123, in apply
    return self.apply_standard()
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/apply.py", line 1174, in apply_standard
    mapped = lib.map_infer(
  File "pandas/_libs/lib.pyx", line 2924, in pandas._libs.lib.map_infer
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/apply.py", line 142, in f
    return func(x, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/io/sas/sas7bdat.py", line 55, in _parse_datetime
    return datetime(1960, 1, 1) + timedelta(seconds=sas_datetime)
OverflowError: days=-1176508800; must have magnitude <= 999999999

In R, things work just fine....:
> library(haven)
> df <- read_sas('my_sas_file.sas7bdat')
> summary(df$DtObgnOrig)
                          Min.                        1st Qu. 
"-3219212-04-24 00:00:00.0000"     "2004-01-27 00:00:00.0000" 
                        Median                           Mean 
    "2008-08-11 00:00:00.0000"     "2009-03-08 10:15:16.7828" 
                       3rd Qu.                           Max. 
    "2014-12-09 00:00:00.0000"     "2027-06-12 00:00:00.0000" 
                          NA's 
                    "93215826"

Anyone have any magic tricks to make the read_sas work, but null out the bad timestamps somehow?

Ummmm, at the risk of stating the blindingly obvious, read the SAS file in R (or SAS!), fix the bad timestamps, write it back out, and then read it using pandas...

I can't do that because I don't have an R server to process the large data involved. This example works on my Mac in R. Otherwise, I won't care to use Pandas, which is always buggy. And, I can't re-process this data in SAS either. IF I could do either, why would I ask this question over here?

Can you do this by installing R packages? This answer may help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55797564/how-to-import-r-packages-in-python

What are the bad values that cause the problems?

"-3219212-04-24 00:00:00.0000"

I mean, what are the bad values in the SAS dataset?  SAS stores date-times in numeric values. But maybe you don't know what's in the SAS data.

You can use r package to read.
from rpy2.robjects import pandas2ri

pandas2ri.activate()

ro.r('library(haven)')

df_R = ro.r('read_sas("my_sas_file.sas7bdat")')

df = pandas2ri.ri2py(df_R)

print(df.head())

This should allow you to read the file in R, where the bad timestamps are handled, and convert the R DataFrame into a pandas DataFrame.
EDIT:
Since you mentioned in comments that only python package are allowed you can use pyreadstat or sas7bdat (deprecated).
Here is the sample code for same:
import pyreadstat 
pyreadstat.read_sas7bdat('my_sas_file.sas7bdat', disable_datetime_conversion = True)


This seems like an intriguing solution. But, unfortunately, I don't have R on the server and the admins won't install R on the server. This python module requires R to have been installed in the first place. Thank you for the creative idea though.

@Gopala : You can try pyreadstat or sas7bdat (deprecated). It might be able to work.

So, I tried pyreadstat.read_sas7bdat('my_sas_file.sas7bdat', disable_datetime_conversion = True) and it is working like a champ. Thank you so much for the pointer. I did not even know this module existed.

Please write up the new module and my call as an answer, and I will accept.
