# 'sklearn.datasets' has no attribute 'samples_generator'

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am trying to reproduce and understand the code included in this document on [Laplacian Eigenmaps for Dimensionality Reduction](http://PyData%20Berlin%202018:%20On%20Laplacian%20Eigenmaps%20for%20Dimensionality%20Reduction) using Google Colab. However, I am getting the following error:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-c1726617ad98> in <module>()
      3 
      4 # Get the data and color map.
----> 5 S_curve, S_colors = datasets.samples_generator.make_s_curve(n_points, random_state=0)
      6 
      7 Axes3D

AttributeError: module 'sklearn.datasets' has no attribute 'samples_generator'
```

I have made sure that I can actually display the plots in [the collection](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/manifold/plot_compare_methods.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-manifold-plot-compare-methods-py) (Swiss roll) by calling additional functions, but it still does not work. Likewise, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41468481/15183594) suggested by Google Colab does not help.

Here is the relevant code:

```
from sklearn import datasets

# Define the number of points to consider. 
n_points = 3000

# Get the data and color map. 
S_curve, S_colors = datasets.samples_generator.make_s_curve(n_points, random_state=0)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO; please notice that it does *not* work by throwing all our code in a question as is - see how to create a [mcve]. Plus, question has nothing to do with `matplotlib` or `google-colaboratory` - kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (edited).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no module named as samples_generator in latest versions of skicit-learn.
So just write

```
S_curve, S_colors = datasets.make_s_curve(n_points, random_state=0)
```