# What function does this code call?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, scikit-learn, scikits

I have this code from scikit docs:

```
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(1)
```

I understand what this code does semantically, but I cannot understand what this code actually calls.
Ok, **numpy** is a name of python module and **np** is just an alias for that. But what is **np.random**? Is it module inside of another module?
I found source code on GitHub and **random** is just a folder inside of **numpy** directory. So **numpy** should be a package, not a module?

Comment: See the [`numpy.random.seed()` documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.seed.html#numpy.random.seed). Does it matter much how the packages and modules are arranged?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7948494/whats-the-difference-between-a-python-module-and-a-python-package

Comment: You seem to be answering your own question. What exactly is the source of your confusion?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I think I was confused because I didn't know that it's possible to import package too.

Comment: @vector2718 Then what purpose did you think a package served? In other words, what else would you do with a package?

Comment: Or perhaps it is enlightening to understand that technically, you import whatever is in the `__init__.py` special module in the package directory when you `import package`.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I thought packages are just for namespace naming. Like packages in Java.

Comment: Technically, at runtime, a "package" is just a `module` object built from the package's `__init__.py`. Any name defined in the `__init__.py` will then become an attribute of this module - as usual for each and any module.

Answer (score 0):

`Numpy` is a package, that contains module `random` which contains method `seed`.

Comment: This is more the comment than an answer.

Comment: @Farseer actually, this *does* answer the question explicitly.

Comment: Is it possible that random is package too? Considering that there is no random.py file but there is a directory called random.