# Django ImportError 'No module named '

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-urls

I'm trying to run a django app but hitting this error when trying to load the page from the browser:

```
No module named views
```

The offending line in urls.py is

```
from landpage.views import txt
```

The file structure looks like this:

**UPDATED**

```
/myproject
    /myproject
        settings.py
    manage.py
    /landpage
        __init__.py
        models.py
        urls.py
        /views
            __init__.py
            landpage.py
            txt.py
```

I've run the command `python manage.py check --traceback` and gotten the result `System check identified no issues (0 silenced).`

I'm very new to django so I am not sure what else to check or what might be causing the issue. This project was just cloned. I have not changed anything.

**UPDATE**

Adding `__init__.py` under the `views` folder fixed this error. There is a new one now in `landpage.py` at the line `from landpage.models import LandpageTeamMember` which says `No module named models`.

Comment: where is manage.py located?

Comment: @dahrens updated the question with more detailed file structure

Comment: Does your landpage folder contains `__init__.py` - it needs one to be treaten as a package.

Comment: It does. It is an empty file.

Comment: Is there also `__init__.py` file in views directory? If yes and it is still not working. Open a django python shell in your projects root folder like that `python manage.py shell`. Try to import there. If there are errors do `import sys; print(sys.path)`. This should show you all root folder from which python tries to import packages and modules. Read for more information: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7948494/whats-the-difference-between-a-python-module-and-a-python-package

Comment: @dahrens, adding `__init__.py` fixed this error but there is a now a different similar one. See updated question and file structure. Also, I don't see anything glaringly wrong with the `sys.path`. I see what I expect to be the root folder and then a ton of virtualenvs paths.

Comment: there is a module called landpage that imports from a package with the same name, that lives two lvls above? I don't know - but maybe this causes the issue - have you already checked the last few commits of the repository?

Comment: ya know what? I just saw that Python 3 is a requirement. I am using Python 2.7... That must be it, right?

Comment: You should also check that virtualenv path thingy above - I'm afraid you'll need to learn about dependency management in python on top. Leave and remove your venv. Setup a fresh one. If the project is well maintained it ships requirements.txt. Use pip in your fresh environment to install external dependencies.

Answer (score 3):

Try putting a `__init__.py` inside the views directory.

Answer (score 0):

You can change from

```
landpage.views import txt
```

to

```
myproject.landpage.views import txt
```

So error says that it cannot import, because it cannot find landpage.views here.
try to go to shell

```
./manage.py shell
```

then in shell try to import

> > > `from myproject.landpage.views import txt`

if there is no error then you are good

Comment: This gives the new error `No module named landpage.views`

Comment: If you have errors with your projects imports (and someone else obviously started on the project) you should start investigating your environment, __before__ you change the imports.

Comment: but investigation using the django shell is a nice approach! :)