# Error while importing function from a module in django webapp

Tags: python, django

I am new to python and django and was trying to make a basic webapp and while doing that, i wanted to add some helper functions in a separate folder inside my app folder.

The structure is :

- app

  - utils

    - testFile.py
  - migrations
  - static
  - urls.py
  - views.py
  - ....
  - ....

My testFile.py has one function for now

```
    def testFunc():
        print("IT WORKS")
```

I am calling it my views.py

```
    from testFile import testFunc
```

and tried the following too

```
    from utils.testFile import testFunc
```

but none of them worked.

After that I checked for directories in which python is looking into using **sys.path**, and utils wasn't there, so I added it using **sys.path.insert()**, but that doesn't work too.

It keeps giving the **no module named testFile** error

I tried creating two simple python files and calling function of one from the other, it works there. So only while I am using in my django webapp, the error is coming. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Nicely formatted good question! Well done.

Comment: Must read about packages and modules  : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7948494/whats-the-difference-between-a-python-module-and-a-python-package

Comment: Thanks. Will read that!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
from .utils.testFile import testFunc
```

Or pass the complete path:

```
from app.utils.testFile import testFunc
```

Comment: Thanks!! It worked. Actually i didn't had "__init__.py" file in my utils folder. Adding that and using your answer helped.

Comment: @The_Cthulhu_Kid Done! Sorry, never asked question before and didn't notice too.

Comment: No worries =) Welcome to Stack Overflow =D