# How to generate sphinx docks in nested directory?

Tags: python, python-sphinx, autodoc

I want to generate sphinx autodoc documentation from scripts in nested folder structure :

```
└── programs
    └── general_name
        └── another_folder
            ├── script1.py
            └── script2.py
```

For some reason script1.py and script2.py is not displayed with autodocs, I'm getting I can see just script name:

```
programs.general_name.another_folder package

¶Submodules

programs.general_name.another_folder.script1 module
programs.general_name.another_folder.script2 module
```

Full folder structure:

```
../
├── docs
│   ├── _build
│   │   ├── doctrees
│   │   │   ├── environment.pickle
│   │   │   ├── index.doctree
│   │   │   └── rst
│   │   └── html
│   │       ├── genindex.html
│   │       ├── index.html
│   │       ├── objects.inv
│   │       ├── rst
│   │       ├── search.html
│   │       ├── searchindex.js
│   │       ├── _sources
│   │       └── _static
│   ├── conf.py
│   ├── index.rst
│   ├── make.bat
│   ├── Makefile
│   ├── rst
│   │   ├── modules.rst
│   │   ├── programs.general_name.another_folder.rst
│   │   ├── programs.general_name.rst
│   │   └── programs.rst
│   ├── _static
│   └── _templates
└── programs
    └── general_name
        └── another_folder
            ├── script1.py
            └── script2.py
```

I'm running this command:

```
/docs $ sphinx-apidoc -f -o rst/ ../programs/ && make html
```

Also I tried:

```
$ sphinx-apidoc -f -o rst/ ../programs/general_name/another_folder/ && make html
```

But script1 module and script2 module are empty in generating html files.

Solution:

Found what was causing the problem - dash symbol "-".
another_folder was actually named get_requests_from_server-10

After renaming folder to get_requests_from_server_10, auto-docks started to work

Answer (score 3):

According to the docs for [`sphinx-apidoc`](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/man/sphinx-apidoc.html):

> sphinx-apidoc is a tool for automatic generation of Sphinx sources that, using the autodoc extension, document a whole **package** in the style of other automatic API documentation tools.
>
> *sourcedir* must point to a **Python package**.

(emphasis added)

According to this [SO Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7948494/whats-the-difference-between-a-python-module-and-a-python-package#7948672):

> Any Python file is a [module](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html), its name being the file's base name without the `.py` extension. A [package](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html#packages) is a collection of Python modules: while a module is a single Python file, a package is a directory of Python modules containing an additional `__init__.py` file, to distinguish a package from a directory that just happens to contain a bunch of Python scripts.

First add an empty `__init__.py` to each `sourcedir`, and see if that resolves the issue.