# Regarding import statement in pox controller

Tags: python, import, controller, sdn, pox

I am reading the source code of pox controller. There is an `import` statement in one module called `l3_editing.py` which is modified based `l3_learning.py`.

The import statement is:

```
from pox.lib.recoco import Timer
```

Because I do not know `Timer`, I just along with the source tree to find this struct. But I cannot find this struct Timer, which really make me confused. It should be in `pox/lib/recoco.py`, but there is no module named `recoco.py` under `lib` package.

Items below `pox/lib:`

[image: pox/lib]

Items below `pox/lib/recoco`:

[image: pox/lib/recoco]

Comment: Look at the contents of the `pox/lib/recoco/__init__.py` file.

Answer (score 2):

The `lib` directory is a python package. It contains an [`__init__.py` file](https://github.com/noxrepo/pox/blob/eel/pox/lib/recoco/__init__.py). When you import a package this will cause any `__init__.py` file to be executed. So what's in there?

Just one line:

```
from recoco import *
```

Great we are getting closer! Lets look in [`recoco.py`](https://github.com/noxrepo/pox/blob/eel/pox/lib/recoco/recoco.py):

```
...
class Timer (Task):
  """
  A simple timer.
...
```

There you have it!

Comment: thanks, I did not realize that the __init__.py will be executed. I thought that just is a tag to present that directory is a package.

Comment: sorry, I can not agree with you after I have try a simple demo. You are right on some aspects. But could you explain what have still confused me:  the statement "from pox.lib.recoco import Timer", it present that I want to import Timer, and Timer is in /pox/lib/recoco, so recoco must be a module which has a suffix .py and Timer must be in recoco.py. The recoco is the end of from keyword, so it won't be a package, because I have try it by a simple demo. And this truth is understandable, because the origin which we want to import from must be a module in the end or it will not be right.

Comment: @Melvin The `recoco` in your `import` statement is a package not a module. When we import `pox.lib.recoco` we are importing the directory `pox/lib/recoco` not the file `pob/lib/recoco/recoco.py`. Because a file called `__init__.py` is present in the package directory, when we import the package then that file is executed. You might enjoy this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7948494/whats-the-difference-between-a-python-module-and-a-python-package

Comment: @Melvin I will not accept your edit because the errors that you have in the example you gave me are caused by running under the Python 3 interpreter. Try your example using the Python 2.7 interpreter (which `pox` requires) and you will find it works. This behaviour changed from Python 2 to Python 3.

Comment: thanks, I have retry it under python2.7, and it works fine. But I still think that the changes on import in python3 are more understandable. Thanks for your instruction, I have learn a lot from it, good bless to you.

Comment: @Melvin Sure, I like the python 3 way better too :-)