# Sharing a function with different modules

Tags: python, python-3.x, module

1. If I have function like this

   ```
   def get_time_format(value, time):
       for item in value:
           time.append(datetime.strptime(str(item),'%H').strftime('%I%P').lstrip('0').upper())
       return time
   ```

   For example, above function I am using across different modules, Instead of code repeation, can I put that in separate file and call them in the module whichever requires them.
2. Second part is related to the first one, so if I have few lines of code which is common. Can I create a file which is having all the common code lines?

   ```
   hierarchy:-
   hello.py
   hello.py/ds/a.py
   hello.py/ds/b.py
   hello.py/ds/c.py
   hello.py/ds/d.py
   ```

   Above `hello.py` is my main file and `a,b,c and d` are modules.

Can some tell me where I can to create a file to share common codes within modules as asked in 1 and 2. I am new to python and using the modules for the first time.

Comment: yes you can create a different file and put all the code it that file. 
Create that file in same directory so you can import function from that file easily

Comment: check this question - you may find it helpful on how to organise your project - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7948494/whats-the-difference-between-a-python-module-and-a-python-package If the number of modules increase, you may want to organise them as a package

Answer (score 0):

save the function as a `example.py` file in any directory. Example `home/ubuntu/Desktop`
Now use the following snippet in any code to use the function

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, 'home/ubuntu/Desktop')
import example as eg

eg.get_time_format(value, time)
```

You can define multiple functions like get_time_format(value,time) foo(x,y) bar(x,y) in `example.py` like  To use them, just type `eg.foo(x,y)` `eg.bar(x,y)`

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using a package for this. See [buran's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53911218/sharing-a-function-with-different-modules#comment94667261_53911218)

Simply create a directory to put your code in and then include an __init__.py file. The __init__.py is a special file that tells python to mark the directory as a python package and therefore make it importable. see [What is __init__.py for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448271/what-is-init-py-for/4116384#4116384]).

**Note**: as __init__.py is a marker file, it is *usually* just an empty file containing no code.

Then you can do the following:

```
# structure
my_directory
-/__init__.py
-foo.py

# foo.py 
def bar(boo):
    print(boo)
```

Subsequently import the function in other modules or an interactive shell as follows:

```
from foo import bar 
bar('ble')
>>>> ble
```

This has the added advantage allowing imports when working outside of the directory of the package:

```
from my_directory.foo import bar 
bar('boo')
>>>>boo
```

or a full import of foo:

```
from my_directory import foo
foo.bar('boo')
>>>>boo
```

Answer (score 0):

create an  `init.py`  in the subfolder ds, and then import all the functions from a, b, c, d in this init file. then it is possible to import ds in hello.py and use all the functions defined in a~d.