# Namespace corrupted when using setup.py and causes AttributeError: module has no attribute

Tags: python, package, setuptools

I wrote a small tool (package) that reuses an existing namespace, `pki.server`. I named my package as `pki.server.healthcheck`. The old namespace **did not** use setuptools to install the package, while my package uses it.

Contents of `setup.py`

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(
    name='pkihealthcheck',
    version='0.1',
    packages=[
        'pki.server.healthcheck.core',
        'pki.server.healthcheck.meta',
    ],
    entry_points={
        # creates bin/pki-healthcheck
        'console_scripts': [
            'pki-healthcheck = pki.server.healthcheck.core.main:main'
        ]
    },
    classifiers=[
        'Programming Language :: Python :: 3.6',
    ],
    python_requires='!=3.0.*,!=3.1.*,!=3.2.*,!=3.3.*,!=3.4.*',
    setup_requires=['pytest-runner',],
    tests_require=['pytest',],
)
```

The installation tree (from scenario 1 below) looks like:

```
# tree /usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pki/
├── __init__.py                     <---- Has methods and classes
├── cli
│   ├── __init__.py                 <---- Has methods and classes
│   ├── <some files>
├── server
│   ├── cli
│   │   ├── __init__.py             <---- Has methods and classes
│   │   ├── <Some files>
│   ├── deployment
│   │   ├── __init__.py             <---- Has methods and classes
│   │   ├── <some files>
│   │   └── scriptlets
│   │       ├── __init__.py         <---- Has methods and classes
│   │       ├── <some files>
│   ├── healthcheck
│   │   ├── core
│   │   │   ├── __init__.py         <---- EMPTY
│   │   │   └── main.py
│   │   └── pki
│   │       ├── __init__.py         <---- EMPTY
│   │       ├── certs.py
│   │       └── plugin.py
│   └── instance.py                 <---- Has class PKIInstance
└── <snip>

# tree /usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pkihealthcheck-0.1-py3.8.egg-info/
├── PKG-INFO
├── SOURCES.txt
├── dependency_links.txt
├── entry_points.txt
└── top_level.txt
```

I read the [official documentation](https://packaging.python.org/guides/packaging-namespace-packages/) and experimented with all 3 suggested methods. I saw the following results:

**Scenario 1: Native namespace packages**

At first, everything seemed smooth. But:

```
# This used to work before my package gets installed
>>> import pki.server
>>> instance = pki.server.instance.PKIInstance("pki-tomcat")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: module 'pki.server' has no attribute 'instance'
```

Now, only this works

```
>>> import pki.server.instance
>>> instance = pki.server.instance.PKIInstance("pki-tomcat")
>>> instance
pki-tomcat
```

**Scenario 2: pkgutil-style namespace packages**
I am restricted from using this method as my other `__init__.py` contain classes and functions

**Scenario 3: pkg_resources-style namespace packages**
Though this method was not-recommended, I went ahead and experimented with it by adding `namespace=pki.server.healthcheck` to my `setup.py`. This made all `pki.*` modules invisible

So I am convinced that Scenario 1 seems to be the closest to what I'm trying to achieve. I was reading an [old post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7948672/1853912) to understand more on how import in python works.

*My question is: Why does a perfectly working snippet break after I install my package?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `__init__.py` files need to import the files. You have two options--[absolute and relative imports](https://realpython.com/absolute-vs-relative-python-imports/):

#### Relative Imports

pki/__init__.py:
`from . import server`

pki/server/__init__.py:
`from . import instance`

#### Absolute Imports

pki/__init__.py:
`import pki.server`

pki/server/__init__.py:
`import pki.server.instance`

Comment: I guess this will resolve the specific scenario I posted. But, there may be multiple modules that need to be corrected. So, I want to learn what's happening behind the screens.

Comment: With a package, the `/xyz/abc/__init__.py` file contents are what gets imported by `import xyz.abc`. So whatever you want to be publicly available needs to be in the init file. Some packages restrict what is exported from the top level--`scipy.sparse` must be imported as `from scipy import sparse` or `import scipy.sparse` by not including `sparse` in the init file to prevent lots of code being loaded automatically.