# Add pytests to my project using setuptools

Tags: python, pytest, setuptools, tox

I'm trying to execute tests defined in `test_csconfig.py` from the following dir structure:

```
# tree .
.
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── healthcheck.conf
├── pki
│   ├── __pycache__
│   │   └── __init__.cpython-37.pyc
│   └── server
│       ├── healthcheck
│       │   ├── core
│       │   │   ├── __init__.py
│       │   │   ├── main.py
│       │   │   └── __pycache__
│       │   │       ├── __init__.cpython-37.pyc
│       │   │       └── main.cpython-37.pyc
│       │   ├── meta
│       │   │   ├── csconfig.py
│       │   │   ├── __init__.py
│       │   │   ├── plugin.py
│       │   │   └── __pycache__
│       │   │       ├── __init__.cpython-37.pyc
│       │   │       └── plugin.cpython-37.pyc
│       │   └── __pycache__
│       └── __pycache__
├── pkihealthcheck.egg-info
│   ├── dependency_links.txt
│   ├── entry_points.txt
│   ├── PKG-INFO
│   ├── SOURCES.txt
│   └── top_level.txt
├── setup.cfg
├── setup.py
└── tests
    └── test_csconfig.py
```

I tried to list the test source directory inside `setup.py`, but it doesn't seem to work

**setup.py**

```
from setuptools import setup


setup(
    # A hyphen ('-') gets converted to underscore ('_') while packaging
    # so avoiding the name pki-healthcheck
    name='pkihealthcheck',
    version='0.1',
    packages=[
        'pki.server.healthcheck.core',
        'pki.server.healthcheck.meta',
    ],
    entry_points={
        # creates bin/pki-healthcheck
        'console_scripts': [
            'pki-healthcheck = pki.server.healthcheck.core.main:main'
        ],
        # register the plugin with ipa-healthcheck
        'ipahealthcheck.registry': [
            'pkihealthcheck.pki = pki.server.healthcheck.meta.plugin:registry',
        ],
        # register the plugin with pki-healthcheck
        'pkihealthcheck.registry': [
            'pkihealthcheck.pki = pki.server.healthcheck.meta.plugin:registry',
        ],
        # plugin modules for pkihealthcheck.pki registry
        'pkihealthcheck.pki': [
            'pki_certs = pki.server.healthcheck.meta.csconfig',
        ],
    },
    classifiers=[
        'Programming Language :: Python :: 3.6',
    ],
    python_requires='!=3.0.*,!=3.1.*,!=3.2.*,!=3.3.*,!=3.4.*',
    setup_requires=['pytest-runner'],
    tests_require=['pytest'],
    test_suite = 'tests',
)
```

The setuptools doesn't recognize the tests defined:

```
# python setup.py test
running pytest
running egg_info
writing pkihealthcheck.egg-info/PKG-INFO
writing dependency_links to pkihealthcheck.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
writing entry points to pkihealthcheck.egg-info/entry_points.txt
writing top-level names to pkihealthcheck.egg-info/top_level.txt
reading manifest file 'pkihealthcheck.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
writing manifest file 'pkihealthcheck.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
running build_ext
============================================================================================================ test session starts =============================================================================================================
platform linux -- Python 3.7.7, pytest-4.6.9, py-1.8.0, pluggy-0.12.0
rootdir: /home/dmoluguw/vmworkspace/experiemnts/pki, inifile: tox.ini
plugins: sourceorder-0.5, multihost-3.0
collected 0 items                                                                                                                                                                                                                            

======================================================================================================== no tests ran in 0.01 seconds ========================================================================================================
```

As you might note, there are missing `__init__.py` under `pki`, `server`, ... dirs. It's because this is a tool that resides inside a major project. Meddling with them cause the overall project to fail. For more information, you can [refer my other question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59431985/namespace-corrupted-when-using-setup-py-and-causes-attributeerror-module-has-no)

I'm pretty sure that I'm missing something obvious but I'm unable to figure it out myself.

**Update 1:**

I figured out that the top-level [`tox.ini`](https://github.com/dogtagpki/pki/blob/master/tox.ini) was creating the issue. Removing this file let the setuptool to identify the tests.

**Update 2:**

After adding a new tox.ini to my tool, the pytest is able to find the tests. However, when executing using tox, the module fails

```
# tox -epy3
ImportError while importing test module '/tmp/workdir/pki/experiemnts/pki/base/server/healthcheck/tests/test_csconfig.py'.
Hint: make sure your test modules/packages have valid Python names.
Traceback:
tests/test_csconfig.py:11: in <module>
    from pki.server.healthcheck.meta.plugin import registry
E   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pki.server.healthcheck'
```

My new `tox.ini`:

```
[tox]
minversion=2.3.1
envlist=py3,flake8,pep8

[testenv]
# sitepackages is needed for ipalib but this confuses the deps for pytest
# pep8 and flake8 so those must be installed globally as well.
sitepackages=True

[testenv:py3]
basepython=python3
commands=
    {envpython} -m pytest
```

Comment: Is the packaging done right? What is the output of `path/to/pythonX.Y -m pip show --files pkihealthcheck`?

Comment: I think the issue was because of the missing `__init__.py` in `pki/server/healthcheck`. The output for your command is empty

Comment: I'll note that using setup_requires and test_requires is considered deprecated. You should instead use tox to inject these requirements. Furthermore, consider using isolated builds https://tox.readthedocs.io/en/latest/example/package.html?highlight=isolated (see https://www.bernat.tech/pep-517-and-python-packaging/ for more on why).