# Python module vs sub-module vs package vs sub-package

Tags: python, module

In Python, What is the differences between module, sub-module, package and a sub-package?

Comment: Please look into this [resource](https://realpython.com/python-modules-packages/).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the difference between a Python module and a Python package?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7948494/whats-the-difference-between-a-python-module-and-a-python-package)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
package
|-- __init__.py
|-- module.py
|-- sub_package
        |-- __init__.py
        |-- sub_module.py
```

Consider **packages** and **sub-packages** as folders and sub-folders containing ****init.py**** file with other python files.

**modules** are the python files inside the package.

**sub-modules** are the python files inside the sub-package.