# ModuleNotFoundError in Juypter notebook after installing local Python package

Tags: python, conda

I tried to install my project as a package so I can import functions from my src folder. In my conda env in the root folder of my project in the terminal I tried `pip install -e ./` and (after uninstalling my first attempt) `python -m pip install -e ./`, both of which resulted in

```
Installing collected packages: gliders
Running setup.py develop for gliders
Successfully installed gliders
```

and the package showing up when I did `conda list`
as

```
Name                    Version                   Build  Channel 
gliders                   0.1.0                     dev_0    <develop>
```

However when I run code with `import gliders` in my Jupyter notebook, I get the following error: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'gliders'`

I am using Python 3.6.13.

How can I fix this error?

Comment: if you are using conda, you need to ensure your conda environment is up. simply by  --> conda activate

Comment: I did ```conda activate myenv```

Comment: okay since your environ is active, conda install pip then try your above pip command again\

Comment: It is the same result as before

Comment: How do you verify that the Jupyter kernel corresponds to the environment?

Comment: Does the package actually export a module named `gliders` (i.e., has a `gliders/__init__.py` file)? [Packages and modules are distinct entities](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7948494/570918).