# How does Python import a module of big Github project?

Tags: python, django, github, directory, python-import

I can't understand how the python import works for big projects on the Github.
Everyone knows the import statement - "from packageName import moduleName".
But for some big projects, for example Django.
I've got tutored "from django.urls import path". (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/http/urls/)
But couldn't find any path.py file under /django/urls directory from its Github structure. (https://github.com/django/django/tree/main/django/urls)
Did I miss any advanced import mechanism?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the difference between a Python module and a Python package?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7948494/whats-the-difference-between-a-python-module-and-a-python-package)

Answer (score 1):

If you look at [`__init__.py`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/9ac92b1efc5ff90e7cce5c47fbd05887d403e4cd/django/urls/__init__.py#L6), it imports the name `path` from [`conf.py`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/9ac92b1efc5ff90e7cce5c47fbd05887d403e4cd/django/urls/conf.py#L84). This makes `path` available as a variable in the `django.urls` module which can be imported.

Comment: Is it a regular way to collect to-export module names with a \_\_all__ array in the \_\_init__.py file? And any recommended tutorials for this? I couldn't find it from those for beginners! :(

Comment: I'm definitely not any kind of expert on this subject, but I found some documentation you could read up on. https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#importing-from-a-package. It seems like the `__all__` list allows the module to explicitly specify which variables and packages get imported when you `import *` from that module.

Comment: rchome, you did me a big favor, thanks a lot.