# Dagster with multiple virtual environments

Tags: python, dagster

I have two python scripts prepared for dagster:

```
dagster1.py
dagster2.py
```

However, they need to run on a different virtual environment each.

```
venv1
venv2
```

Is it possible to run both on the same dagster server? If so, how? If not, what would be the alternative or workaround?

Answer (score 1):

you can set up your Dagster workspace to load from multiple Python environments by setting the `executable_path` field in your `workspace.yaml` file - there's an example here: https://docs.dagster.io/concepts/repositories-workspaces/workspaces#multiple-python-environments

Comment: Thanks. What would be difference in this YAML between python_package and python_file?

Comment: Hi, sorry for the delay. Python packages vs. Python files/modules are explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7948494/whats-the-difference-between-a-python-module-and-a-python-package#:~:text=A%20package%20is%20a%20collection,a%20bunch%20of%20Python%20scripts.