# How to import a file from another directory in Python

Tags: python, import, importerror

I want to import a file from another Directory

The main file Directory is
/storage/emulated/0/BOT/main.py

I want to import
/storage/emulated/0/BOT/Plugins/spam.py in main.py

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7948494/whats-the-difference-between-a-python-module-and-a-python-package

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448271/what-is-init-py-for

Comment: Hey, welcome to stackoverflow. Please help others to help you by providing a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to show what you have done, what kind of error you get, and what you tried to solve the error. Thanks.