# How to write a Python module/package?

Tags: python, python-2.7, upload, python-module, python-packaging

I've been making Python scripts for simple tasks at work and never really bothered packaging them for others to use. Now I have been assigned to make a Python wrapper for a REST API. I have absolutely no idea on how to start and I need help.

**What I have:**

(Just want to be specific as possible) I have the [virtualenv](http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/basics/how-to-use-python-virtualenv/) ready, it's also [up in github](https://github.com/yowmamasita/pyfirefly), the .gitignore file for python is there as well, plus, the [requests library](https://requests.readthedocs.io/) for interacting with the REST API. That's it.

Here's the current directory tree

```
.
├── bin
│   └── /the usual stuff/
├── include
│   └── /the usual stuff/
├── lib
│   └── python2.7
│       └── /the usual stuff/
├── local
│   └── /the usual stuff/
└── README.md

27 directories, 280 files
```

I don't even know where to put the .py files, if I ever make one.

**What I wanted to do:**

Make a python module install-able with "pip install ..."

If possible, I want a general step by step process on writing Python modules.

Comment: I would start with [chapter 6 of the tutorial (2.7)](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html), or [here for 3.x](http://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html)  Search the internet for [python module tutorial](http://www.google.com/search?q=python+module+tutorial) and you'll find plenty of others.

Comment: No one answered the pip part

Comment: https://github.com/MacHu-GWU/pygitrepo-project this library helps you to create project skeleton from scratch, and the feature you need is out of box.

Comment: Just wanna say: missed opportunity to name it "pyrefly"

Answer (score 467, accepted):

A module is a file containing Python definitions and statements. The file name is the module name with the suffix `.py`

create `hello.py` then write the following function as its content:

```
def helloworld():
   print "hello"
```

Then you can import `hello`:

```
>>> import hello
>>> hello.helloworld()
'hello'
>>>
```

To group many `.py` files put them in a folder. Any folder with an `__init__.py` is considered a module by python and you can call them a package

```
|-HelloModule
  |_ __init__.py
  |_ hellomodule.py
```

You can go about with the import statement on your module the usual way.

For more information, see [6.4. Packages](http://docs.python.org/dev/tutorial/modules.html#packages).

Comment: would that last one be: from HellowModule import hellomodule? Could that be hello in the module folder, so it would be from HelloModule import hello

Comment: Currently playing around with Python and this answer has to be one of the most helpful I've come across. Explains it very well, thank you.

Comment: the "pip install" command won't work, also you have to be in the same directory to use it

Comment: Can you tell me how to include files such as `dll`, `exe`, ect. in it? Thanks!

Answer (score 273):

**Python 3 - UPDATED 18th November 2015**

*Found the accepted answer useful, yet wished to expand on several points for the benefit of others based on my own experiences.*

**Module:** A module is a file containing Python definitions and statements. The file name is the module name with the suffix .py appended.

**Module Example**: Assume we have a single python script in the current directory, here I am calling it *mymodule.py*

The file *mymodule.py* contains the following code:

```
def myfunc():
    print("Hello!")
```

If we run the python3 interpreter from the current directory, we can import and run the function *myfunc* in the following different ways (you would typically just choose one of the following):

```
>>> import mymodule
>>> mymodule.myfunc()
Hello!
>>> from mymodule import myfunc
>>> myfunc()
Hello!
>>> from mymodule import *
>>> myfunc()
Hello!
```

Ok, so that was easy enough.

Now assume you have the need to put this module into its own dedicated folder to provide a module namespace, instead of just running it ad-hoc from the current working directory. This is where it is worth explaining the concept of a **package**.

**Package**: Packages are a way of structuring Python’s module namespace by using “dotted module names”. For example, the module name A.B designates a submodule named B in a package named A. Just like the use of modules saves the authors of different modules from having to worry about each other’s global variable names, the use of dotted module names saves the authors of multi-module packages like NumPy or the Python Imaging Library from having to worry about each other’s module names.

**Package Example**: Let's now assume we have the following folder and files. Here, **mymodule.py** is identical to before, and **__init__.py** is an empty file:

```
.
└── mypackage
    ├── __init__.py
    └── mymodule.py
```

The __init__.py files are required to make Python treat the directories as containing packages. For further information, please see the Modules documentation link provided later on.

Our current working directory is one level above the ordinary folder called **mypackage**

```
$ ls
mypackage
```

If we run the python3 interpreter now, we can import and run the module **mymodule.py** containing the required function *myfunc* in the following different ways (you would typically just choose one of the following):

```
>>> import mypackage
>>> from mypackage import mymodule
>>> mymodule.myfunc()
Hello!
>>> import mypackage.mymodule
>>> mypackage.mymodule.myfunc()
Hello!
>>> from mypackage import mymodule
>>> mymodule.myfunc()
Hello!
>>> from mypackage.mymodule import myfunc
>>> myfunc()
Hello!
>>> from mypackage.mymodule import *
>>> myfunc()
Hello!
```

Assuming Python 3, there is excellent documentation at: [Modules](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html)

In terms of naming conventions for packages and modules, the general guidelines are given in PEP-0008 - please see [Package and Module Names](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#package-and-module-names)

Modules should have short, all-lowercase names. Underscores can be used in the module name if it improves readability. Python packages should also have short, all-lowercase names, although the use of underscores is discouraged.

Comment: Nice simple explanation. What if you want to keep another folder inside mypackage ?

Comment: The include totally depends on what you did wrote. In the case of you put stuff outside a function on your module, you'll fire it when calling like `import mypackage`. In the case you wanna import just a function from a module (even a file) is better to use `from module import function`. In the case a subfolder `from subfolder.module import function` so you can simply call `function()` witthout fire other code parts. Also, do not use `from module import *` if you don't really need.

Comment: The only question left is how can I get the package to import everything on `import mypackage`? Adding `import mymodule` to `__init__.py` does not work..

Comment: Neat explanation! however, I have a question if numpy is a package how can I execute numpy.cos(1) in my interpreter because that seems to be a module name in between go missing. No?

Comment: How about pip ?

Comment: Wow, this answer accidentally answered what I was actually looking for... importing every function from a module (from module import *). The reason I'm doing this is to import a module that import modules in order to use all the functions without adding a billion A.B.C.D... extensions. Thanks man!

Answer (score 234):

Since nobody did cover this question of the OP yet:

> **What I wanted to do:**
>
> Make a python module install-able with "pip install ..."

Here is an absolute minimal example, showing the basic steps of preparing and uploading your package to PyPI using `setuptools` and `twine`.

**This is by no means a substitute for [reading at least the tutorial](https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/distributing-packages/), there is much more to it than covered in this very basic example.**

Creating the package itself is already covered by other answers here, so let us assume we have that step covered and our project structure like this:

```
.
└── hellostackoverflow/
    ├── __init__.py
    └── hellostackoverflow.py
```

In order to use `setuptools` for packaging, we need to add a file `setup.py`, this goes into the root folder of our project:

```
.
├── setup.py
└── hellostackoverflow/
    ├── __init__.py
    └── hellostackoverflow.py
```

At the minimum, we specify the metadata for our package, our `setup.py` would look like this:

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(
    name='hellostackoverflow',
    version='0.0.1',
    description='a pip-installable package example',
    license='MIT',
    packages=['hellostackoverflow'],
    author='Benjamin Gerfelder',
    author_email='benjamin.gerfelder@gmail.com',
    keywords=['example'],
    url='https://github.com/bgse/hellostackoverflow'
)
```

Since we have set `license='MIT'`, we include a copy in our project as `LICENCE.txt`, alongside a readme file in reStructuredText as `README.rst`:

```
.
├── LICENCE.txt
├── README.rst
├── setup.py
└── hellostackoverflow/
    ├── __init__.py
    └── hellostackoverflow.py
```

At this point, we are ready to go to start packaging using `setuptools`, if we do not have it already installed, we can install it with `pip`:

```
pip install setuptools
```

In order to do that and create a `source distribution`, at our project root folder we call our `setup.py` from the command line, specifying we want `sdist`:

```
python setup.py sdist
```

This will create our distribution package and egg-info, and result in a folder structure like this, with our package in `dist`:

```
.
├── dist/
├── hellostackoverflow.egg-info/
├── LICENCE.txt
├── README.rst
├── setup.py
└── hellostackoverflow/
    ├── __init__.py
    └── hellostackoverflow.py
```

At this point, we have a package we can install using `pip`, so from our project root (assuming you have all the naming like in this example):

```
pip install ./dist/hellostackoverflow-0.0.1.tar.gz
```

If all goes well, we can now open a Python interpreter, I would say somewhere outside our project directory to avoid any confusion, and try to use our shiny new package:

```
Python 3.5.2 (default, Sep 14 2017, 22:51:06) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from hellostackoverflow import hellostackoverflow
>>> hellostackoverflow.greeting()
'Hello Stack Overflow!'
```

Now that we have confirmed the package installs and works, we can upload it to PyPI.

Since we do not want to pollute the live repository with our experiments, we create an account for the [testing repository](https://test.pypi.org/), and install `twine` for the upload process:

```
pip install twine
```

Now we're almost there, with our account created we simply tell `twine` to upload our package, it will ask for our credentials and upload our package to the specified repository:

```
twine upload --repository-url https://test.pypi.org/legacy/ dist/*
```

We can now log into our account on the PyPI test repository and marvel at our freshly uploaded package for a while, and then grab it using `pip`:

```
pip install --index-url https://test.pypi.org/simple/ hellostackoverflow
```

As we can see, the basic process is not very complicated. As I said earlier, there is a lot more to it than covered here, so go ahead and [read the tutorial](https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/distributing-packages/) for more in-depth explanation.

Comment: Will my package be published right after `setuptools`?

Comment: @U9-Forward No, the publishing is done with `twine`, but you can test your package locally before publishing after you created it with `setuptools`.

Comment: How can I uninstall it after this command `pip install ./dist/hellostackoverflow-0.0.1.tar.gz`? I don't see anyone mention about uninstalling, don't see it in the `pip list` neither.

Comment: Suppose our package requires some dependencies which are by default not in standard python library. Then how will we make pip install those dependencies too?

Comment: LICENCE has a typo there, should be LICENSE

Answer (score 8):

Once you have defined your chosen commands, you can simply drag and drop the saved file into the Lib folder in your python program files.

```
>>> import mymodule 
>>> mymodule.myfunc()
```

Answer (score 2):

Make a file named "hello.py"

If you are using Python 2.x

```
def func():
    print "Hello"
```

If you are using Python 3.x

```
def func():
    print("Hello")
```

Run the file. Then, you can try the following:

```
>>> import hello
>>> hello.func()
Hello
```

If you want a little bit hard, you can use the following:

If you are using Python 2.x

```
def say(text):
    print text
```

If you are using Python 3.x

```
def say(text):
    print(text)
```

See the one on the parenthesis beside the define? That is important. It is the one that you can use within the define.

Text - You can use it when you want the program to say what you want. According to its name, it is text. I hope you know what text means. It means "words" or "sentences".

Run the file. Then, you can try the following if you are using Python 3.x:

```
>>> import hello
>>> hello.say("hi")
hi
>>> from hello import say
>>> say("test")
test
```

For Python 2.x - I guess same thing with Python 3? No idea. Correct me if I made a mistake on Python 2.x (I know Python 2 but I am used with Python 3)

Answer (score 2):

You can create `pkg` package which has `__init__.py`(Empty file) and `file.py` as shown below. *Each package should have `__init__.py` which is empty according to what the doc says in [A simple project](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/tutorials/packaging-projects/#a-simple-project) and you can see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7948494/whats-the-difference-between-a-module-and-package-in-python/76431054#76431054) explaining the difference between [module](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-module) and [package](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-package) in Python and you can see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3658084/how-to-create-upload-and-install-a-package-for-pypi/76417107#76417107) explaining how to create, upload and install a package for [TestPyPI](https://test.pypi.org/) and [PyPI](https://pypi.org/):

```
test
 |-pkg # Here
 |  |-__init__.py
 |  └-file.py
 └-main.py
```

And, `file.py` has the code below:

```py
# "pkg/file..py"

PI = 3.14

def hello():
    return "Hello"

class Person:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
```

Now, you can import the code from `pkg/file.py` and use it as shown below:

```py
# "main.py"

from pkg.file import PI, hello, Person

print(PI) # 3.14
print(hello()) # Hello
p = Person("John")
print(p.name) # John
```

And in `pkg` package, you create `sub_pkg` package which has `__init__.py`(Empty file) and `sub_file.py` as shown below:

```
test
 |-pkg
 |  |-__init__.py
 |  |-file.py
 |  └-sub_pkg # Here
 |     |-__init__.py
 |     └-sub_file.py
 └-main.py
```

And, `sub_file.py` has the code below:

```py
# "pkg/sub_pkg/sub_file.py"

GRAVITY = 9.8

def world():
    return "World"

class Animal:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
```

Now, you can import the code from `pkg/sub_pkg/sub_file.py` and use it as shown below:

```py
# "main.py"

from pkg.sub_pkg.sub_file import GRAVITY, world, Animal

print(GRAVITY) # 9.8
print(world()) # World
a = Animal("Dog")
print(a.name) # Dog
```

Answer (score 1):

A module is a file containing Python definitions and statements. The file name is the module name with the suffix .py

Create a file called hello.py with the following function as its content:

```
def helloworld():
   print "hello"
```

Then you can

```
import hello
hello.helloworld()
```

To group many .py files, put them in a folder. Any folder with an **init**.py is considered a module by python and you can call them a package.

|-HelloModule
|_ **init**.py
|_ hellomodule.py