# how to add a module to Anaconda

Tags: python, ubuntu, anaconda

This is what i get when i do "***python -V***"

**Python 2.7.11 :: Anaconda 2.4.0 (64-bit)**
I usually use my terminal to play with IDLE.But now i have also installed IDLE shell.

I tried *import sys;sys.path* on both.They throw different paths.
My Terminal returned the path with anaconda in it.

I tried to install a module following these steps.

1. python setup.py sdist
2. sudo python setup.py install

Then i opened IDLE(shell).I was able to import and also use my module.

I wanna do the same in Anaconda..I tried using conda install filename.py.It doesn't work.
Please help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are several ways to add a module to Anaconda.

- `conda install <package>`
- `pip install <package>`
- `python setup.py install` (if you are in the source directory, no sudo required if anaconda is in your home directory)

To make a package for others to use you will need to put it up where people can access it like Github.
You will have to make a config file (takes yaml file manipulation) you can read up on how to make/distribute packages here. http://conda.pydata.org/docs/build_tutorials/pkgs.html

Now to answer your question:  There is a difference between using a file and using a module/package.  A file can just be imported in another python program using `import filename` where filename.py is the name of the file you want to use.  to make that a module you want to take a look at the answer to this question. [How to write a Python module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15746675/how-to-write-a-python-module)

Comment: Thanks man!.python setup.py install worked.Why is it lik that?how does sudo make a diff like that.I am a beginner.Thanks anyways.

Comment: Anaconda is installed in your home directory. You have the ability to add/change things in your home directory all you want.  Sudo is a command to run programs as someone else, like the root user.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the answer above.
But just be careful when using: pip install 
Apparently a deprecated pip could generate problems like "Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement"
So just to be on the safe side update your version.

That was my case. After looking at this link:
https://pypi.org/project/opencv-python/

It said:

> A: Most likely the issue is related to too old pip and can be fixed by running
>   `pip install --upgrade pip`.

So I decided to try updating mine. And it worked...
Hope this was helpful!

Comment: Hi, after I updated the version of pip, the problem disappeared. I believe in the link I put there was a comment on how the version of pip could create some problems. This was the case for me anyway.

Comment: Please [edit] your post to make it more obviously an answer to the question by adding the information from your link.

Comment: Did you look at your post after editing it? Frankly it does not seem so. Please try for more readability in the future. This might help with that. https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help Also, please take the [tour].

Comment: It does however seem a decent answer now. (I just cannot verify, for lack of knowledge on my side. So please understand that I cannot upvote.)