# python module installation no admin rights windows

Tags: python, module

No admin rights and proxy (Windows 7) is a key here. I want to intall a python module in my user local file.
Previously I got anaconda (Version 1.6.0) installed and I used the solution mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30148335/install-python-module-using-a-zip-file) and it worked like a charmed. Few days later my company installed Python 2.7.13 on my machine and when I try

```
pip install newmodule.zip
```

I got Errno 13: Permission denied Error. Apparently with this instruction the newmodule tries to be installed in: `C:\\Program Files\\Python27\\site-packages\\` where new Python is installed and where I have no admin rights, so I got the error.

I have tried using:
     `conda install newmodule.bz2` and

`conda install C:\myuser\path\for\python27\newmodule.bz2` and also the solutions mentioned [here2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35436350/how-to-add-a-module-to-anaconda) But still I have no success. Any hint to get a new python module installed under the charcateristics mentioned above? This is driving me crazy

Comment: Have you tried running the *pip command* on a command prompt opened as an *administrator*?

Comment: @Kasramvd , yeap I've tried but no way to get into administrator mode