# Importing Modules I Create

Tags: python, import

I have a nagging problem with importing modules I create. Although I can save them alright, when I open the Python shell to import it, it gives me this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   
File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>     
import draw ImportError: 
No module named 'draw'.
```

This is very frustrating because I can run it directly from the file but when I want to import it, I get that error message.

Comment: what is your directory structure?? and check if you are missing a __init__.py inside your module directory

Comment: @armak of course means `__init__.py`

Comment: @armak Thank you for the help but I'm very new to programming so please break it down into layman's terms for me.

Comment: @Dokua you can refer to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15746675/how-to-write-a-python-module

Comment: Every python package needs to have a `__init__.py` file. So if you got something like a classes subdirectory the parentfolder (where your script lays) has to have an init. You can then import it like `from <parentfolder>.classes import <class>`

Comment: Thanks for the help!