# How to make a module called 'func' in python

Tags: python

I am trying to make a module but not sure what exactly they are. I will post what the requirements of it are.

**REQUIREMENTS**
Make a module called 'funct' that holds the following information -

1. def total(val) - returns sum of all # in the list 'val'.
2. def sub(val) - returns the difference of all # in the list 'val'.
3. def times(val) - returns the product of all # in the list 'val'.
4. def div(val) - returns the result of dividing all # in the list 'val'. If first # is 0, then the result is 0. If any other # are 0, use sys.exit to stop it & display 'invalid list.'

Here is what I'm thinking it is supposed to be like:

```
import funct

funct.total([1, 2, 3, 4])
funct.sub([1, 2, 3, 4])
funct.times([1, 2, 3, 4])
funct.div([1, 2, 3, 4])
```

Comment: How can you not know what they are? Surely whoever gave you this assignment taught the basics first. Were you absent for that class?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to make a python module or function and use it while writing other programs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39978375/how-to-make-a-python-module-or-function-and-use-it-while-writing-other-programs)

Comment: Or the more canonical [How to write a Python module/package?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15746675/2745495)

Answer (score 0):

A module in python is a file containing code, i.e. you need to create a file called `funct.py` in the same folder as your `main.py` (or whatever you called the example above).

Then you need to implement each of the required functions, i.e. you code should look like

```
def total(val):
    pass

def sub(val):
    pass

def times(val):
    pass

def div(val):
    pass
```

Then in place of `pass` you need to code up the required logic

Comment: Ok so when the module 'funct.py' is run, it is not supposed to give any results? And could you by chance help out with any of the logic given the requirements?

Answer (score 0):

A module is nothing else like a separate python file. So you can just create a file `funct.py` and define all the needed functions, so:

**funct.py**:

```py
def total(lst : list) -> int:
    acc = 0
    for i in lst:
        acc += i
    return acc  # return the accumulated sum

def sub(...):
    pass

def times(...):
    pass

def div(...):
    pass
```

Then in another python file, but in the same folder, create the `main.py` file or any other filename which imports this module and uses the defined functions:

**main.py**

```py
import funct

funct.total([1, 2, 3, 4])
funct.sub([1, 2, 3, 4])
funct.times([1, 2, 3, 4])
funct.div([1, 2, 3, 4])
```

[Here](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_modules.asp) you can see some further reading and informations about python modules.