# Importing another .py file throwing an error

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to import a .py file named 'main' within the same directory as my main file.

```
from .settings import *
```

When I run it I get this error

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:/Users/user_1/Desktop/Projects/program/main.py", line 5, in <module>
        from .settings import *
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '__main__.settings'; '__main__' is not a package
```

Why isn't this working and how do I fix it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15746675/how-to-write-a-python-module

Comment: You mean you're trying to import a module named `settings` from your `main.py` file? BTW `.` is for relative imports; and `settings` and `main` are not good names for your own modules

Comment: Have you tried `import settings`?

Answer (score 0):

You need to have the package in library folder of python. For me
keeping any module inside this directory works

```
C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages
```