# how to make this code to become module

Tags: python, python-module

This is the Python code [code](https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/two-factor-auth-flask/blob/master/app.py)

```
import os
import base64
from io import BytesIO
from flask import Flask, render_template, redirect, url_for, flash, session, \
    abort
from werkzeug.security import generate_password_hash, check_password_hash
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_login import LoginManager, UserMixin, login_user, logout_user, \
    current_user
from flask_bootstrap import Bootstrap
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import StringField, PasswordField, SubmitField
from wtforms.validators import Required, Length, EqualTo
import onetimepass
import pyqrcode

# create application instance
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object('config')

# initialize extensions
bootstrap = Bootstrap(app)
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
lm = LoginManager(app)


class User(UserMixin, db.Model):
    """User model."""
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(64), index=True)
    password_hash = db.Column(db.String(128))
    otp_secret = db.Column(db.String(16))

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(User, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        if self.otp_secret is None:
            # generate a random secret
            self.otp_secret = base64.b32encode(os.urandom(10)).decode('utf-8')

    @property
    def password(self):
        raise AttributeError('password is not a readable attribute')

    @password.setter
    def password(self, password):
        self.password_hash = generate_password_hash(password)

    def verify_password(self, password):
        return check_password_hash(self.password_hash, password)

    def get_totp_uri(self):
        return 'otpauth://totp/2FA-Demo:{0}?secret={1}&issuer=2FA-Demo' \
            .format(self.username, self.otp_secret)

    def verify_totp(self, token):
        return onetimepass.valid_totp(token, self.otp_secret)


@lm.user_loader
def load_user(user_id):
    """User loader callback for Flask-Login."""
    return User.query.get(int(user_id))


class RegisterForm(FlaskForm):
    """Registration form."""
    username = StringField('Username', validators=[Required(), Length(1, 64)])
    password = PasswordField('Password', validators=[Required()])
    password_again = PasswordField('Password again',
                                   validators=[Required(), EqualTo('password')])
    submit = SubmitField('Register')


class LoginForm(FlaskForm):
    """Login form."""
    username = StringField('Username', validators=[Required(), Length(1, 64)])
    password = PasswordField('Password', validators=[Required()])
    token = StringField('Token', validators=[Required(), Length(6, 6)])
    submit = SubmitField('Login')


@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')


@app.route('/register', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def register():
    """User registration route."""
    if current_user.is_authenticated:
        # if user is logged in we get out of here
        return redirect(url_for('index'))
    form = RegisterForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        user = User.query.filter_by(username=form.username.data).first()
        if user is not None:
            flash('Username already exists.')
            return redirect(url_for('register'))
        # add new user to the database
        user = User(username=form.username.data, password=form.password.data)
        db.session.add(user)
        db.session.commit()

        # redirect to the two-factor auth page, passing username in session
        session['username'] = user.username
        return redirect(url_for('two_factor_setup'))
    return render_template('register.html', form=form)


@app.route('/twofactor')
def two_factor_setup():
    if 'username' not in session:
        return redirect(url_for('index'))
    user = User.query.filter_by(username=session['username']).first()
    if user is None:
        return redirect(url_for('index'))
    # since this page contains the sensitive qrcode, make sure the browser
    # does not cache it
    return render_template('two-factor-setup.html'), 200, {
        'Cache-Control': 'no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate',
        'Pragma': 'no-cache',
        'Expires': '0'}


@app.route('/qrcode')
def qrcode():
    if 'username' not in session:
        abort(404)
    user = User.query.filter_by(username=session['username']).first()
    if user is None:
        abort(404)

    # for added security, remove username from session
    del session['username']

    # render qrcode for FreeTOTP
    url = pyqrcode.create(user.get_totp_uri())
    stream = BytesIO()
    url.svg(stream, scale=3)
    return stream.getvalue(), 200, {
        'Content-Type': 'image/svg+xml',
        'Cache-Control': 'no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate',
        'Pragma': 'no-cache',
        'Expires': '0'}


@app.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    """User login route."""
    if current_user.is_authenticated:
        # if user is logged in we get out of here
        return redirect(url_for('index'))
    form = LoginForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        user = User.query.filter_by(username=form.username.data).first()
        if user is None or not user.verify_password(form.password.data) or \
                not user.verify_totp(form.token.data):
            flash('Invalid username, password or token.')
            return redirect(url_for('login'))

        # log user in
        login_user(user)
        flash('You are now logged in!')
        return redirect(url_for('index'))
    return render_template('login.html', form=form)


@app.route('/logout')
def logout():
    """User logout route."""
    logout_user()
    return redirect(url_for('index'))


# create database tables if they don't exist yet
db.create_all()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', debug=True)
```

I was trying to split it to become a module but it is something what is not working.

I was naming auth.py and I was trying on views.py to add the routes for login and register and did not worked I was following this [example](http://greenash.net.au/thoughts/2015/06/splitting-a-python-codebase-into-dependencies-for-fun-and-profit/) but

Could you explain me exactly how to split it if I have to import all the imports from auth.py to views.py?

Comment: Added note try to paste your code here not in link...

Comment: could you explain me how because when I am trying to paste it, it appears like a disaster this was the reason for what I was linked the code

Comment: paste your code here as it is in your file and select all and do CTRL+K  .

Comment: It appears like a disaster unless you mark it as code with the `{ }` button.

Comment: I've done it nowhere is saying to paste the code to select it and after to press the {} button everyone is saying to use the {} button :(

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers.

Comment: @Ben: I am new here and beginner unfortunately, but if you have read my post, you will understand I was asking how to make it a module not if is working  ... unfortunately if you follow the code owner instructions it will work perfect but I was asking how to split it as module if I was naming auth.py and how to make it to link it in views.py. Is it anyone who was understanding my task?

Comment: thank you to everyone who contributed to block my acc ... keep the knowledge for your self pls do not answer at my task ... for you is important how you wish to be publish the task not to help a beginner .. however what shall I do if the start is creepy?!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/modules.html), a module is a file containing Python definitions and statements. The file name is the module name with the suffix .py appended.

You can import modules by simply using `import moduleNameHere`.

Your problem could be that you want to create a package, not a module. Again, according to the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#packages), packages are a way of structuring Python’s module namespace by using “dotted module names”. For example, the module name A.B designates a submodule named B in a package named A. Just like the use of modules saves the authors of different modules from having to worry about each other’s global variable names, the use of dotted module names saves the authors of multi-module packages like NumPy or the Python Imaging Library from having to worry about each other’s module names.

The simplest way to create a package, is to create a file named `__init__.py` in the same directory as the script you want to *package*.

You can check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47298178/6745924) for more details. But basically if you want a package called `hellostackoverflow`, you should have a directory structure like this one:

```
.
└── hellostackoverflow/
    ├── __init__.py
    └── hellostackoverflow.py
```

Good luck!