# how do I install my modual onto my local copy of python on windows?

Tags: python, python-3.x, cmd, module

I'm reading headfirst python and have just completed the section where I created a module for printing nested list items, I've created the code and the setup file and placed them in a file labeled "Nester" that is sitting on my desktop. The book is now asking for me to install this module onto my local copy of Python. The thing is, in the example he is using the mac terminal, and I'm on windows. I tried to google it but I'm still a novice and a lot of the explanations just go over my head. Can someone give me clear thorough guide?.

Comment: You can use CMD.to do the same with proper Environment variables set up(i.e. add path to python executable and site packages)

Comment: See the answer from @arcseldon at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15746675/how-to-write-a-python-module-package

Answer (score 0):

On Windows systems, third-party modules (single files containing one or more functions or classes) and third-party packages (a folder [a.k.a. directory] that contains more than one module (and sometimes other folders/directories) are usually kept in one of two places: `c:\\Program Files\\Python\\Lib\\site-packages\\` and `c:\\Users\\[you]\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\`.

The location in Program Files is usually not accessible to normal users, so when PIP installs new modules/packages on Windows it places them in the user-accessible folder in the Users location indicated above. You have direct access to that, though by default the `AppData` folder is "hidden"--not displayed in the File Explorer list unless you set FE to show hidden items (which is a good thing to do anyway, IMHO). You can put the module you're working on in the `AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\` folder.

You still need to make sure the folder you put it in is in the `PATH` environment variable. `PATH` is a string that tells Windows (and Python) where to look for needed files, in this case the module you're working on. Google "set windows path" to find how to check and set your path variable, then just go ahead and put your module in a folder that's listed in your path.

Of course, since you can add any folder/directory you want to `PATH`, you could put your module anywhere you wanted--including leaving it on the Desktop--as long as the location is included in `PATH`. You could, for instance, have a folder such as `Documents\\Programming\\Python\\Lib` to put your personal modules in, and use `Documents\\Programming\\Python\\Source` for your Python programs. You'd just need to include those in the `PATH` variable.

FYI: Personally, I don't like the way python is (by default) installed on Windows (because I don't have easy access to `c:\\Program Files`), so I installed Python in a folder off the drive root: c:\Python36. In this way, I have direct access to the `\\Lib\\site-packages\\` folder.

Comment: The install of Python under "Program Files" is a good design for system maintenance and stability. The fact that a normal user account does not have permission to write and delete there is a good thing. To do that does, and should, require an administrator account.

Comment: @lit: Yes, that's true. But I am the owner and administrator of my own system, and I don't like the system interfering with what I want to do. So I work around it.