# Where to put files of my python application?

Tags: python, linux

I've created application in python for linux and because it grown I grouped functions into separate files which main script imports. Now program is done and I want to share it with the world, I also want installation of this program to be as easy as typing one command. I know that I can use setuptools to move executable to /usr/bin but where I put rest of my files? Which directory in system will be best suited for that?

Comment: Use `PyPi` to package your program

Comment: Everything is written in the documentation https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: Also useful is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15746675/how-to-write-a-python-module-package and https://python-packaging.readthedocs.io/en/latest/.