# Why does my Python package not find my class?

Tags: python, python-3.x, package

I'm trying to convert my large Python script into a package.  I have the following file structure:

```
bin/foob # The main Python script
lib/foob/__init__.py
```

The file lib/foob/__init__.py has one class defined:

```
class Node(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.test = True
```

The file bin/foob has:

```
import foob

def get_nodes():
    x = foob.Node()

get_nodes()
```

I'm running the script with:

```
$ PYTHONPATH=PYTHONPATH:~/foob/lib ~/foob/bin/foob
```

The error I get is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/person/foob/bin/foob", line 6, in <module>
    x = get_nodes()
  File "/home/person/foob/bin/foob", line 4, in get_nodes
    node_obj = foob.Node()
AttributeError: module 'foob' has no attribute 'Node'
```

This structure seems identical to another program I wrote which works just fine.  What am I missing?

Comment: Have you checked for typos? Seems you have  `foob` and `foop` coexisting together.

Comment: That's because I changed the names for this post.  There are no typos in the real code.

Comment: I would recommend that you go through [How to write a python Module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15746675/how-to-write-a-python-module-package).

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is **Naming Conflict**. You're importing module `bin/foob` rather than  `lib/foob`.

### Python Import Sequence

When you `import` something, the Python Interpreter would search in the following sequence:

> 1. built-in Module.
> 2. Current Directory.
> 3. Environment Variable: PYTHONPATH
> 4. Some other Directories.(irrelevant to this question)

the last three of which can be seen by `import sys; sys.path`

---

Seemingly you're in `bin/foob`, thus `bin/foob` is what you import. It can be checked by `import os; os.getcwd()`.

I recommend you to avoid the same name.

Comment: I am in /tmp when I get the error.  I renamed lib/foob to lib/foobtest and changed `import foob` to `import foobtest` and I get the same error.

Comment: Have you changed `x = foob.Node()` into `x = foobtest.Node()`?