# Repackage a modified library originally installed through pip

Tags: python, pip, setuptools, distutils, pypi

I installed a library through pip that only worked with Python2. I modified the source a bit to make it work with Python3, however I would like to repackage my modified version so that I can move it to another PC. How can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See any of these references from the docs/stackoverflow:

- [An Overview of Packaging for Python](https://packaging.python.org/overview/)
- [Packaging Python Products (Tutorial)](https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/packaging-projects/)
- [Packaging and Distributing Projects (Guide)](https://packaging.python.org/guides/distributing-packages-using-setuptools/)
- [this minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47298178/6837399) from [bgse](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2511718/bgse) at StackOverflow

The process essentially consists of:

- creating the package through directory structure and `__init__.py`
- using `setuptools` to specify project metadata
- installing with `pip`
- optionally uploading to PyPI with `twine`.

Answer (score 1):

Your package should have a setup.py that come with it

`python3 setup.py bdist_wheel`

This will create directory called `dist` containing a python wheel file

`ls -l dist\*.whl`

Copy that file to the other system and

`pip3 install <file_name>.whl`

Comment: This assumes that the two platforms are the same, which might not be the case, and the install might fail. A source distribution (`python setup.py sdist`) would be guaranteed to work.