# How to call functions from other python files

Tags: python, function, file, call

I am working on a Python Project and want to call multiple functions from other python files, but I'm having trouble. Can someone please help me?

Comment: Please read [ask]

Comment: You import them. What exactly are you having trouble with?

Comment: I want to call a function from another python file. For example: I want to call a function inside of Application.py from Main.py.

Comment: please do a little search on how to create your own python module , and come back with your code if things not going well

Comment: you can start from here [how-to-write-a-python-module-package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15746675/how-to-write-a-python-module-package)

Comment: Well, I just created my account and i'm new to Stack Overflow

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to write a Python module/package?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15746675/how-to-write-a-python-module-package)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each of your Python file can act as a module, that you can import.

for example for numpy you just type 'import numpy' and then you'll be able to use numpy.sin() function.

by default you can only append modules located in sys.path. So What you can do is:

```
import sys
if not (<folder_with_your_function> in sys.path):
    sys.path.append( <folder_with_your_function> )

import <your_function>
```

Comment: Thx! I will do that now.

Comment: You're welcome.. It's not the best way to do it but it will work. if you want to be cleaner, take a look at 'init.py' files.