# Why is my items module not properly being imported?

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I have a scrapy project that utilizes an item pipeline. I used the Scrapy "startproject" command to create my project so I think my folder structure is accurate.

I've tried moving the VersionSpider.py file to the outer directory, the same directory as the items module, and that works. However when I run the scrapy crawl command it can't find the spider since it's not in the proper directory.

File Structure:
~[files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xc9R1.jpg)

```py
from CFBScraper.items import VersionItem
```

```py
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'CFBScraper'
```

Comment: Check out [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14132789/relative-imports-for-the-billionth-time) it should help you out.

Comment: @MyNameIsCaleb That did look helpful, but when I use the package name, CFBScraper, I'm still getting the error.

Comment: Can you post your item and pipeline scripts?

Comment: Actually, post the spider too please. Does the spider script run at all? Is that error specific to that import items line?

Comment: Your `CFBScraper` folder is not a Python module. [Make it a Python module](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15747198/939364).

Answer (score 0):

Its because your both folders are with same name `CFBScraper`

Do this, rename your top folder to something else like `CFB_Scraper` or something other and it will work

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Unfortunately, renaming the top level folder does not solve the problem of the "ModuleNotFoundError"