# Importing custom testing library in Robot Framework

Tags: python, robotframework

I am writing a custom testing library for `Robot Framework` in `Python` and I want to import it like this:

```
Library         CustomLibrary
```

I put the folder containing the source code on the `PYTHONPATH` but I am still getting the error: `Importing test library 'CustomLibrary' failed: ImportError: No module named CustomLibrary`

The `CustomLibrary` class is defined in the `__init__.py` file, like in the `AppiumLibrary` like this:

```
from CustomLibrary.keywords import *

class CustomLibrary(_CustomKeywords):
    ROBOT_LIBRARY_SCOPE = 'GLOBAL'
```

How can I solve this problem, so I can import it in Robot Framework? I want to keep the class definition inside the init file.

Comment: What is the CustomLibrary path?

Comment: `/Users/<user-name>/Desktop/Python/CustomLibrary/`

Comment: Have you checked this post? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15746675/how-to-write-a-python-module-package

Comment: Yes. I have in all of my packages an `__init__.py` file

Comment: When you say _"put the folder containing the source code on PYTHONPATH"_, what do you mean? If `CustomLibrary` is a folder in the folder `foo`, are you putting `foo` on PYTHONPATh, or `foo/CustomLibrary`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make sure that the folder containing `CustomLibrary` is on PYTHONPATH.

For example, the following works as expected for me:

1. create a folder in /tmp named CustomLibrary
2. create a file named /tmp/CustomLibrary/__init__.py
3. define a class named CustomLibrary in /tmp/CustomLibrary/__init__.py
4. define a method in the CustomLibrary class
5. import the library in a test with `Library  CustomLibrary`
6. add /tmp to PYTHONPATH and run robot. For example, `robot --pythonpath /tmp  example.robot`