# How to create my own pip install module after creating my code?

Tags: python, module

I want to create my own module that can be used via the -pip install function in cmd. I already have the code for my module but I cannot upload it for my friends to use in other computer through -pip. Anyone knows how to do this? Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to write a Python module/package?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15746675/how-to-write-a-python-module-package)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pip fetches files from [PyPi](https://pypi.org/).

You need to package your python project up. [Details can be found here.](https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/packaging-projects/)

Packaging a project includes a few crucial steps:

1. Folder/File structure
2. `__init__` file
3. setup.py
4. Readme and license
5. Creating an archive
6. Uploading to PyPi