# How to update a local package with pip

Tags: python, pip

The answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15746675/how-to-write-a-python-module-package) show how to install a local package using pip. However, I am also interested in knowing how to update a package. For example, if I previously had installed package with version 1.0.0, and now I want to replace it with 1.0.1, how would I do that? One method I can think of is to use pip uninstall and then install the new one, but is there a more elegant way?

Comment: @YOLO: Maybe you can put it as the answer, also describing it a little bit.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+update+package

Answer (score 9):

I do the following to update a local python package:

1. Using `-e` flag tells `pip install` to read package in an editable mode, which means you don't need to reinstall the package after making your changes. They get detected automatically.
2. Using `-U` flag tells `pip install` to upgrade the package.

So, in your case, following should work:

```
pip install -e your_package_directory
```