# How can I load different functions from different modules with same name

Tags: python, import

I have the following structure

```
my_scripts
    group_A
        group_A1
            main.py
            dbFunctions.py
        group_A2
            main.py
            dbFunctions.py
    group_B
        scripting_Im_running_things_from.py
        dbFunctions.py
```

I want to load  one function from each of the `main.py`s, and am trying to do it with `sys.path.append`. But because the folder I am running my main script from (group_B) has `dbFunctions.py` as well, none of the other two models' functions (ie. `group_A1\main.py` and `group_A2\main.py`) can utilise functions from their respective `dbFunctions.py` modules so I am getting an import error:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'my_function_in_groupA1_dbFunctions' from 'dbFunctions' (C:\my_scripts\group_B\dbFunctions.py)
```

> (I also tried renaming `group_B\dbFunctions.py` to `group_B\_dbFunctions.py` and adding the `group_A1` and `group_A2` 
>   to sys.path does allow me to import functions from whichever of `group_A1`'s and `group_A2`'s `main.py` 
>   I choose to import from first, but then for the second one it is impossible to make it look at the 
>   second folder; because it has loaded one function from a given `main.py`, seemingly no other `main.py` > can be considered.)

Is it preferebale to add `init.py`s in all folders or can this be done by using `importlib` ?

Apologies for not creating a re-producible example, I cannot do it I believe for this question.

Comment: It is not only preferable, but necessary, to add `__init__.py` files in order to use the source files as packages.

Comment: So this cannot be resolved by making explicit imports using `importlib`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to write a Python module/package?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15746675/how-to-write-a-python-module-package)

Comment: It depends; this post explains how to convert a script into a package. If this is the only way to resolve what I am asking in this question then it might. If however there is a straightforward way to explicitly ask it to 'first import a function specifically from group_A1\main.py, then import a function specifically from group_A2\main.py' then it doesn't. But I am not sure what is the case, the former or the latter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use relative imports. For example:

```
# ../my_scripts/group_A/group_A1/main.py

# Import foo from ../my_scripts/group_A/group_A1/dbFunctions.py
from .dbFunctions import foo

# Import bar from ../my_scripts/group_A/group_A2/dbFunctions.py
from ..group_A2.dbFunctions import bar

# Import baz from ../my_scripts/group_B/dbFunctions.py
from ...dbFunctions import baz
```

Comment: I can't even make `from .dbFunctions import foo` run (for the module in the same folder) as I am getting `ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package`. Is adding the dot the only change that needs to be done in order for this to work?

Comment: Add empty `__init__.py` files to your directories, so they becomes packages.