# Why is my program throwing exception 'xyz' is not a package?

Tags: python-3.x, module, package

I have the following setup in my **Spyder** ide:

[image]

this program is showing the following exception:

```
runfile('C:/Users/pc/source/repos/python_package_and_module_test/main.py', wdir='C:/Users/pc/source/repos/python_package_and_module_test')


Reloaded modules: jupyter_client.session, zmq.eventloop, zmq.eventloop.ioloop, tornado.platform, tornado.platform.asyncio, tornado.gen, zmq.eventloop.zmqstream, jupyter_client.jsonutil, jupyter_client.adapter, spyder, spyder.pil_patch, PIL, PIL._version, PIL.Image, PIL.ImageMode, PIL.TiffTags, PIL._binary, PIL._util, PIL._imaging, cffi, cffi.api, cffi.lock, cffi.error, cffi.model
Traceback (most recent call last):

 File "C:\Users\pc\source\repos\python_package_and_module_test\main.py", line 1, in <module>
import token.factoryclass as a

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'token.factoryclass'; 'token' is not a package
```

how can I resolve this issue?

---

source code:

my files are as follows:

## .\

### python_package_and_module_test.py

```
import token.factoryclass as a

var = a.factoryclass();
var.print();
```

### factoryclass.py

```
class factoryclass(object):
    def print(object):
        print("factoryclass")
```

### tokenclass.py

```
class tokenclass(object):
    def print(object):
        print("tokenclass")
```

## factory\

### factoryclass.py

```
class factoryclass(object):
    def print(object):
        print("factory.factoryclass")
```

### tokenclass.py

```
class tokenclass(object):
    def print(object):
        print("factory.tokenclass")
```

## token\

### factoryclass.py

```
class factoryclass(object):
    def print(object):
        print("token.factoryclass")
```

### tokenclass.py

```
class tokenclass(object):
    def print(object):
        print("token.tokenclass")
```

---

However, the same package and module structure is working in repl.it:

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to write a Python module/package?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15746675/how-to-write-a-python-module-package)

Comment: you need a file (can be empty) `__init__.py` in the `token/` directory

Comment: @Macattack, adding `__init__.py` didn't work.

Comment: This might be an issue with the the places python searches for imports. Generally the first place it checks is your current working directory, then it checks all the normal system paths for installed packages. I can't find documentation on `runfile('C:/Users/pc/source/repos/python_package_and_module_test/python_package_and_module_test.py', wdir='C:/Users/pc/source/repos/python_package_and_module_test')` to know if it switches your current working directory. You can check these things with `os.getcwd()` (your current working directory) and `sys.path` (your import locations, `''` is cwd)