# copy a dataframe to new variable with method chaining

Tags: python, pandas, method-chaining

Is it possible to copy a dataframe in the middle of a method chain to a new variable?
Something like:

```
import pandas as pd

df = (pd.DataFrame([[2, 4, 6],
                    [8, 10, 12],
                    [14, 16, 18],
                    ])
      .assign(something_else=100)
      .div(2)
      .copy_to_new_variable(df_imag)  # Imaginated method to copy df to df_imag.
      .div(10)
      )
```

`print(df_imag)` would then return:

```
    0   1   2   something_else
0   1.0 2.0 3.0 50.0
1   4.0 5.0 6.0 50.0
2   7.0 8.0 9.0 50.0
```

`.copy_to_new_variable(df_imag)` could be replaced by `df_imag = df.copy()` but this would result in compromising the method chain.

Comment: Ok. Method chaining in pandas does not improve the speed of evaluation. Chained methods don't get optimised. It would make absolutely no difference if you just stopped the chain, took a manual copy, and then continued processing the df

Comment: Agree with roganjosh's recommendation that coding with explicit side-effects will be confusing, clearer to use separate assignment and expression chaining. Why are you doing this? just to make a copy for debug? or production code?

Comment: It should be for production. It would increase readability if I could use something like `.copy_to_new_variable(df_imag)` instead of the `:=` operator. Thank you for your thoughts.

Comment: mouwsy: `.copy_to_new_variable(df_imag)` would be syntactic sugar for `df_imag :=`. But pandas [`df.copy()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.copy.html intentionally doesn't allow you use an assignment target on the RHS, they really don't want you putting assigns with side-effects in a pipeline. Why do you want to do this in production? That sort of code will break lots of things, like optimization (e.g. numba). By the way, do you want the copy to be a deep-copy or shallow copy? Is your dataframe ints, floats, strings, arbitrary objects...?

Comment: Very, very important to understand that `df_imag = df` **does not copy the data frame**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creating variables dynamically [is not a good idea](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1373164/16343464), but you can easily take advantage of mutable objects like dictionaries.

Adding a new DataFrame method to do this seamlessly:

```
from pandas.core.base import PandasObject

### this only needs to be done once per session
def to_name(df, dic, name, copy=False):
    dic[name] = df.copy() if copy else df
    return df
    
PandasObject.to_name = to_name
###

tmp = {}

df = (pd.DataFrame([[2, 4, 6],
                    [8, 10, 12],
                    [14, 16, 18],
                    ])
      .assign(something_else=100)
      .div(2)
      .to_name(tmp, 'after_div2', copy=True)
      .div(10)
      )

print(tmp['after_div2'])

print(df)
```

Output:

```
# tmp['after_div2']
     0    1    2  something_else
0  1.0  2.0  3.0            50.0
1  4.0  5.0  6.0            50.0
2  7.0  8.0  9.0            50.0

# df
     0    1    2  something_else
0  0.1  0.2  0.3             5.0
1  0.4  0.5  0.6             5.0
2  0.7  0.8  0.9             5.0
```

If you don't want to monkey patch the DataFrame objects, use [`pipe`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pipe.html):

```
def to_name(df, dic, name, copy=False):
    dic[name] = df.copy() if copy else df
    return df

tmp = {}

df = (pd.DataFrame([[2, 4, 6],
                    [8, 10, 12],
                    [14, 16, 18],
                    ])
      .assign(something_else=100)
      .div(2)
      .pipe(to_name, tmp, 'after_div2')
      .div(10)
      .pipe(lambda df: print('\nQuick alternative:', df, sep='\n') or df)
      )

print(tmp['after_div2'])
```

#### printing

In the same line you can also add a chainable `print` method, or again use a lambda in [`pipe`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pipe.html):

```
from pandas.core.base import PandasObject

### this only needs to be done once per session
def df_print(df, *args):
    if args:
        print(*args)
    print(df)
    return df
    
PandasObject.print = df_print
###

df = (pd.DataFrame([[2, 4, 6],
                    [8, 10, 12],
                    [14, 16, 18],
                    ])
      .print()
      .assign(something_else=100)
      .div(2)
      .print('\nAfter 2:')
      .div(10)
      .pipe(lambda df: print('\nQuick alternative:', df, sep='\n') or df)
      )
```

Output:

```
    0   1   2
0   2   4   6
1   8  10  12
2  14  16  18

After 2:
     0    1    2  something_else
0  1.0  2.0  3.0            50.0
1  4.0  5.0  6.0            50.0
2  7.0  8.0  9.0            50.0

Quick alternative:
     0    1    2  something_else
0  0.1  0.2  0.3             5.0
1  0.4  0.5  0.6             5.0
2  0.7  0.8  0.9             5.0
```

#### As a module

You could also [create a module](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15746675/16343464):

`pandas_debug.py`

```
from pandas.core.base import PandasObject

def df_print(df, *args):
    if args:
        print(*args)
    print(df)
    return df
    
PandasObject.print = df_print

def to_name(df, dic, name, copy=False):
    dic[name] = df.copy() if copy else df
    return df

PandasObject.to_name = to_name
```

Then in your code:

```
import pandas as pd
import pandas_debug

tmp = {}
df = (pd.DataFrame([[2, 4, 6],
                    [8, 10, 12],
                    [14, 16, 18],
                    ])
      .assign(something_else=100)
      .div(2)
      .to_name(tmp, 'after_div2')
      .div(10)
      .print()
      )
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this is what I was looking for. Just for better understanding: What does `from pandas.core.base import PandasObject` and `PandasObject.to_name = to_name` do? Can I drop these? Because the code also works without these.

Comment: This is required to add a new DataFrame method (`to_name`), which otherwise wouldn't exit, but you only have to run it once per session and it will work for all DataFrames. You do not need it if you use the `pipe` approach.

Answer (score 3):

Use `:=` operator:

```py
df = (df_imag := df.assign(new_var=100).div(2)).div(10)
print(df)
print(df_imag)
```

Prints:

```
     0    1    2  new_var
0  0.1  0.2  0.3      5.0
1  0.4  0.5  0.6      5.0
2  0.7  0.8  0.9      5.0

     0    1    2  new_var
0  1.0  2.0  3.0     50.0
1  4.0  5.0  6.0     50.0
2  7.0  8.0  9.0     50.0
```

Comment: should probably note that this is a Python 3.8+ op.