# Install a newly created package by me in anaconda

Tags: python, anaconda

I have a package named SMTP_email saved as .py file. Is there a way I can bring this into my anaconda environment as package?

Comment: If it `SMTP_email.py` is locally saved in the save directory, you can just do `import SMTP_email` in the py file you need?

Comment: Otherwise see [How to create, upload and install a package for PyPI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3658084/how-to-create-upload-and-install-a-package-for-pypi) (a little dated) and just do `pip install` to get it. you can also upload it to a github repository and just do `pip install` from there

Comment: @SurajShourie, I want to be able to retrieve it from the anaconda environment. I will give your second suggestion a try too!